# Get keys of a Typescript interface as array of strings

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've a lot of tables in [Lovefield](https://github.com/google/lovefield) and their respective Interfaces for what columns they have.

Example:

```ts
export interface IMyTable {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  isDeleted: boolean;
}
```

I'd like to have the property names of this interface in an array like this:

```ts
const IMyTable = ["id", "title", "createdAt", "isDeleted"];
```

I cannot make an object/array based on the interface `IMyTable` directly which should do the trick because I'd be getting the interface names of the tables dynamically. Hence I need to iterate over these properties in the interface and get an array out of it.

How do I achieve this result?

Comment: This answer is the most correct in my opinion, unfortunately there's not easier way as mentioned: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909566/get-keys-of-a-typescript-interface-as-array-of-strings#answer-43922291

Answer (score 111):

As of *TypeScript 2.3* (or should I say *2.4*, as in *2.3* this feature contains [a bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15192) which has been fixed in *typescript@2.4-dev*), you can create a custom transformer to achieve what you want to do.

Actually, I have already created such a custom transformer, which enables the following.

https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys

```
import { keys } from 'ts-transformer-keys';

interface Props {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
const keysOfProps = keys<Props>();

console.log(keysOfProps); // ['id', 'name', 'age']
```

Unfortunately, custom transformers are currently not so easy to use. You have to use them with the *TypeScript* transformation API instead of executing tsc command. There is [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14419) requesting a plugin support for custom transformers.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i already saw and installed this custom transformer yesterday but since this uses typescript 2.4, this of no use to me as of now.

Comment: In that thread, someone just added a means to patch typescript and allow custom transformers.  https://github.com/nonara/ts-patch.  You can (maybe) make it easier to use your custom transformer!

Comment: Unfortunately, the package is broken, whatever I do I am always getting `ts_transformer_keys_1.keys is not a function`

Comment: works well with vite https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/7580#discussioncomment-3099161

Comment: It might work well, But adding a new npm package just to get Interface keys wouldn't justify the requirement

Comment: do not work (tested in browser) and do not explains the solution.
ts_transformer_keys_1.keys is not a function

Comment: I can't get this to work with vite, not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: `Type 'string[]' has no signatures for which the type argument list is applicable`

Answer (score 72):

I faced a similar problem: I had a giant list of properties that I wanted to have both as an interface (compile-time), and an object (run-time) out of it.

**NOTE: I didn't want to write (type with keyboard) the properties twice!**  DRY.

---

One thing to note here is, interfaces are enforced types at compile-time, while objects are mostly run-time. ([Source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes))

As @derek mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48464139/2321594), the common denominator of **interface** and **object** can be a class that serves both a **type** and a **value**.

So, TL;DR, the following piece of code should satisfy the needs:

```js
class MyTableClass {
    // list the propeties here, ONLY WRITTEN ONCE
    id = "";
    title = "";
    isDeleted = false;
}

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

// This is the pure interface version, to be used/exported
interface IMyTable extends MyTableClass { };

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

// Props type as an array, to be exported
type MyTablePropsArray = Array<keyof IMyTable>;

// Props array itself!
const propsArray: MyTablePropsArray =
    Object.keys(new MyTableClass()) as MyTablePropsArray;

console.log(propsArray); // prints out  ["id", "title", "isDeleted"]


// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

// Example of creating a pure instance as an object
const tableInstance: MyTableClass = { // works properly!
    id: "3",
    title: "hi",
    isDeleted: false,
};
```

([Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeAVMAjEBTAwuK0DeAUNMdAPSnQgCWEALtLQBbrQAOATgPavq1Xoxm7dABpoAeQByAGQCa0AOoAlAJKJEAUUkTJmDURJUAJtAC80AEQWA3AeJ9aGM5Zt3oNACLoMtdCfMAZmAgEOi2AL4EBOTQiIw07jBMLKwArsLuAHa+7EHALABu6OwQVJyZYrSc0CgsqaFGpOgAHqyc7L5GBFTZxXksKgjIaCwtvplGMEOoGNiQMHjQ4bbRFAAKXKxJ8DzQkHuZe+zsYPCV1bXQLW0dfgS0OyzTIxvcEACCx6fOnyfwADwAa3Q8E4AWggyQM3QAD5bDFXlsjn93LRQiAAgBCAjAcp0NibD5feAALjgUJehN+31MbnEKAAVuhgLQAHTA+AQAAUmXQAHdycNZjhuQBKUV7KYUjCIol-Wy4zIQTgYVkgTgAcy5HDe1PgousZAoHB6aOgnFS9AABQBtCzGCxiCwODCOyyeby8PwWAC6URiGmaYAAtqwnGDoMBhGA+JkNXs2OkWD06GBMvlJQdzYzmbQcXj6LRoSolUX0+gyc9hfNnIsYnz2oCYDqeOwQPBsSR3EYyRYAMyOtwuiuWeKDrsenx+MlBEKiAjLIA) is the above code in Typescript Playground to play more)

PS. If you don't want to assign initial values to the properties in the class, and stay with the type, you can do the constructor trick:

```
class MyTableClass {
    // list the propeties here, ONLY WRITTEN ONCE
    constructor(
        readonly id?: string,
        readonly title?: string,
        readonly isDeleted?: boolean,
    ) {}
}

console.log(Object.keys(new MyTableClass()));  // prints out  ["id", "title", "isDeleted"]
```

[Constructor Trick in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeAVMAjEBTAwuK0DeAUNMdAPSnQgCWEALtLQBbrQAOATgPavq1Xoxm7dABpoAeQByAGQCa0AOoAlAJKJEAUUkTJmDURLBOAOzrsArsFqd2ACgMkSwsABMTIeNCouA-AC5oMypjAHMRB0doZzdjDwYqWgx-QNp2YLCIx2j3TxoAEXQMWnRfAJROTgwwY3DHAEp8AF8CZoJyaERGGi8YJhZWc2EvY2L2ADMwYBYAN3R2CCoTMWtoFBZzCBLSdAAPVhtilwJg0Ymp6BUEZDQWXeLjFxgr1AxsSBg8aEaAbgICI1MlXQADoQJwQrZxCgAFboKzAgDW6HgEFsxnQAHc4EgXlgcKi6oTvsR2hwTjBOOZ6NAANoAIm8dLEdL4iXQTOgDIgBSKJTpAF0gA).

Comment: The `propsArray` is only accessible when you initialized the keys though.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "initialized" @denkquer.   In the first example, `propsArray` is available before the `tableInstance` if that's what you mean, so clearly before the initialization of the instance.

However, if you are referring to the fake values assigned in `MyTableClass`, those are just there to shortly imply the "type" of the properties.  If you don't want them, you can go with the constructor trick in the PS example.

Comment: In my understanding a value is initialized when it has any value. Your "constructor trick" is misleading because you can't just replace the `MyTableClass` with the latter one and expect to receive keys in the `propsArray` as uninitialized vars and types are stripped at runtime. You always have to supply them with some kind of default value. I've found that initializing them with `undefined` is the best approach.

Comment: @denkquer sorry, my Constructor trick was missing `readonly` and `?` on the paramteres.  I just updated that.  Thanks for pointing out.  Now I think it works the way you said is misleading and cannot work. :)

Comment: why you need to this much of things? since you initialise your class when it define you can simply use `console.log(Object.keys(new MyTableClass()))` it will do the job

Comment: @KrishanthaDinesh we need properties during compile-time (TypeScript and type checking in IDE) not during run-time (JavaScript).

Answer (score 54):

Maybe it's too late, but in version 2.1 of TypeScript you can use `keyof` to get the type like this:

```ts
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    location: string;
}

type K1 = keyof Person; // "name" | "age" | "location"
type K2 = keyof Person[];  // "length" | "push" | "pop" | "concat" | ...
type K3 = keyof { [x: string]: Person };  // string
```

Source: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types

Comment: Thanks for the answer but not sure if it helps someone to use statically created Types from interface. IMHO, we can use interfaces/types interchangeably in most of the cases. Plus this would require manual creation of types for multiple interfaces. However the solution looks good if someone just needs to get types out of an interface.

Comment: I downvoted because this does not solve the question as stated. The goal is to get a list of `string[]` out of a type; not to get the key-type with `keyof MyType`.

Comment: @CharlesCapps this can be easily solved by wrapping keyof as in `type K2 = (keyof Person)[]`

Comment: type K2 = (keyof Person)[] did not compile forme @AndreiSirotin.  Any way to get the array of strings?

Comment: @CharlesCapps `type K2 = (keyof Person)[]` is still a type, not an array.

Comment: I agree this does not answer the main question. It returns a type and not a value, so it will be lost during compilation. It is great if you want some more static validation, but you cannot do any runtime check with this. The question was about parsing those values into a runtime variable, not deriving a new type.

Comment: It only allow you to create a type, I want to create an array

Answer (score 50):

The following requires you to list the keys on your own, but at least TypeScript will enforce `IUserProfile` and `IUserProfileKeys` have the exact same keys ([`Required<T>` was added in TypeScript 2.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html)):

```
export interface IUserProfile  {
  id: string;
  name: string;
};
type KeysEnum<T> = { [P in keyof Required<T>]: true };
const IUserProfileKeys: KeysEnum<IUserProfile> = {
  id: true,
  name: true,
};
```

Comment: Pretty cool trick. Now it's easy to enforce implementing all keys of `IUserProfile` and would be easy to extract them from the const `IUserProfileKeys`. This is exactly what I've been looking for. No need to convert all my interfaces to classes now.

Comment: I downvoted as agin it is not "interface as array of strings" that I want to get from type or interface. I do not want to get type, I know how to do it. I think it is shortly speeking, how to convert type to variable.

Comment: That's kind of halfway there. A type can be created from an object, but an object cannot be created from a type.

Answer (score 40):

## Safe variants

Creating an array or [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) of keys from an interface with safety compile-time checks requires a bit of creativity. Types are erased at run-time and object types (unordered, named) cannot be converted to tuple types (ordered, unnamed) [without resorting to non-supported techniques](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298).

### Comparison to other answers

The here proposed variants all consider/trigger a compile error in case of duplicate or missing tuple items given a reference object type like `IMyTable`. For example declaring an array type of `(keyof IMyTable)[]` cannot catch these errors.

In addition, they don't require [a specific library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43922291/5669456) (last variant uses `ts-morph`, which I would consider a generic compiler wrapper), emit a tuple type [as opposed to an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54308812/5669456) (only first solution creates an array) or wide array type (compare to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62477194/5669456) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58315855/5669456)) and lastly [don't need classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59806829/5669456).

### Variant 1: Simple typed array

```
// Record type ensures, we have no double or missing keys, values can be neglected
function createKeys(keyRecord: Record<keyof IMyTable, any>): (keyof IMyTable)[] {
  return Object.keys(keyRecord) as any
}

const keys = createKeys({ isDeleted: 1, createdAt: 1, title: 1, id: 1 })
// const keys: ("id" | "title" | "createdAt" | "isDeleted")[]
```

`+` easiest `+-` manual with auto-completion `-` array, no tuple

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkCeAVOAjAGxQG8AoZZYAEwC5kQBXAWz2gG5zkxgwi6BnMFFABzDhQRQIcSFQCCYOgBEZEcZX5KIRWXTwB7fUTggOAX1KkA9FeQAlCAn1QqXTAAcUEEPwZT%20ADTIAO4oABZwAG4oIPrIVPoMhCjOyEzA-PyiyADWEJiByJFwBAwQ-MgIJsis9BAiRAiypDAMIE3A%20iCVUqoA0vn8ABR5mA5OLnTjzlQAPKP6MGhYuMlBJpgAfACUdCP5i8s4%20ETbANoAushkFFJgft0A8ngAVo5gAHSjw6PTLtvIOAVDakCykJw%20MC5QbIAC8PWkkAGBSGxA0Wh0EFoyAAjEFJIisQo6HiuDw%20LigtQScgzNtrLYIYJoQU9gAiahs5AAH2QbO4vAgXN5bIJqnkYGFfIyGIgsjZ5wupCAA)

If you don't like creating a record, take a look at [this alternative with `Set` and assertion types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkCeAVOAjAGxQG8AoZZYAEwC5kQBXAWz2gG5zkxgwi6BnMFFABzDhQRQIcSFQCCYOgBEZEcZX5KIRWXTwB7fUTggOAX1KkE%20kIOQBrCJn7IAvPQgB3ZAGUIYAAoAbQAiahCAGmQQ7l4ISOjJaVkFBLDNbX8IKhCAXWQ4F2tbMABKSzBMAAcUPzAAaSd%20AB5sZAgAD0gQKhc65pNMAD4ht2Q2zu7e339m0BhoNFGAfjRkOhAIADdoCuqUVH4AUQBHBjgCVoiAVVH3IOx8yYgelyDr-NX3p66X6YfPlwoAwUHR3hEQsgqPoIPwQAByMDtX49aJRR7rZAPCHQ2EIpHPHoJD6kAD0pOQ-GATCqBGAMGA2S4%20yiCAAFhAEPZKDBkJh9AwPEywPpkAgGIJ9ExgAAvFA8MkUgAGQVySuQVSkO3ALjgyAAVFRgIJhHgGLJ9WKbEbuDYLsyalF%20KLPCgECZkGyTFRKCBkAwQMAbMh9LzHM49jVkHJ%20PxoGBWsipi4hCC7uNSJUozG41AwBgcPgiGMc-HmodTudLuHQ2gsLhCBAonVGs5mlmILXw-wRkNFe0oFB9FBdUjrDTgEQALTcJjy3lK7vq73IJUFhtEdXQ-GeuA7SlwOcOJqWcnII6D4fIw%2002GWUCQWCIA71osQAD6IH0qB9ZAosT4SkhFEdQklUeRFGQFRIHUY0tB0bI9EMYxTFICwrBsOxu0-b8fXcTZvDqYIYh4Ig0jAlIwDSODMlkPICiKTCykjFBSzzdc33fC8oAARhLWMywrM4LmaGteQ4xtm38VsWg7Lsmhwn9e0zfZowE9jX0bLjBwAJn43MEyEqtRKcWsJKIRSqCkhomnbfZ5OcZSMNsIwIAAOgIfQRACbtyiAA).

---

### Variant 2: Tuple with helper function

```
function createKeys<T extends readonly (keyof IMyTable)[] | [keyof IMyTable]>(
    t: T & CheckMissing<T, IMyTable> & CheckDuplicate<T>): T {
    return t
}
```

`+` tuple `+-` manual with auto-completion `+-` more advanced, complex types

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkCeAVOAjAGxQG8AoZC5YAEwC5kQBXAWz2gG5zKxgwj6AzmCigA5p0rIEUCHEjUAgmHoARORAmVgAlRCLz6eAPZGicEJwC+pUgHpbyAMIALCAgDWAgDRUYybMjM2gIQAsjuEJhhMFBGzMgAqhSkYJgADigubu7owWIAPAEQAB6QINRhMnDURiAEmMjmmADaALo+SSVlFcgASm5GUNT5QiIgoj5NAHxTyAC8yGSSzQDSVCDhkUZ+Ca30a10Q5WHYzUys0K3IAPwMEABu0Mj7pJbNEZjbiVeHx3ePUBu-mewIAZMgAEQAUSgsSg9CCAgEYk2UQhdgcADkjJB6AADALg6GwwYIvLjVECCF4qhhABWjCEyBggwYwCQaBUUOQ0DhAgAdMgAJpGRhSUUEaiNAgCIzIADuIkgyDxIAe0Dx-Js9icrg83l8wIQtTAcFAYWojDSBHZ6iokGYAhS6UyevcKitNoQ6kKPNKRx6VRqdQaTTaswWS0ozQACgBGdaor7YPaQgD6MAIcFEaYhfu6TskxGQsYATImPsnUzHy78evGgWqAc8uJIKKcaz9-X8O3GrrcIRmszm8-Qm083pW-Cmbq2S732pCYXD6JbrbbIBCrvQF68bDBGCAEDxalIqpAVpEBL665VZMH6sgABRTtBYXCECAASjayAAPiWr4YDg+BEK0UxPnOyhgrq2S5EiBTYD4wEfkQszglkHgeuu3qQIUUxfjuixzjIYCMFAGxgHupDGiATJGO4-QCIwBBgPMZ6yBeV5Ps0EI0BCPgQjwfAQAJkLSJxECKGAYl8ToegQPIW5fsgOoAPIrDR54QJeUQ8Xx1DKapDi8oMPiIsiFK8BAjpaZJukCPpACOjDFEZOqmVAPggLUAC0zByAgzgotZzB2eoDn6fxgnCUQskSeo0mydouj6FJyWGa0KkeSSXnIGuXp2qFNi0bKRD8gQRiiE+DFMSxYBftqDiQEI0Ssq4BAZICqQZE6PUoNgCYLJhOTkqI+S8WkcZbj4xZTfQTQ+GkpYLSADSWLMOqTdNVxEsupKBGNlLov1-jlsNbrwZZ43bbJy0zYsyDzY0a1LStL3rZtDi3YJ92tM6GT+AAzOxI3YYVeHNHGPilj4QPgQDA0ACyg264MbhAE3Q8gsPIH2UxAA)

#### Explanation

`createKeys` does compile-time checks [by merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) the function parameter type with additional assertion types, that emit an error for not suitable input. `(keyof IMyTable)[] | [keyof IMyTable]` is a ["black magic" way](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179#issuecomment-422606990) to force inference of a tuple instead of an array from the callee side. Alternatively, you can use [const assertions / `as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) from caller side.

`CheckMissing` checks, if `T` misses keys from `U`:

```
type CheckMissing<T extends readonly any[], U extends Record<string, any>> = {
    [K in keyof U]: K extends T[number] ? never : K
}[keyof U] extends never ? T : T & "Error: missing keys"

type T1 = CheckMissing<["p1"], {p1:any, p2:any}> //["p1"] & "Error: missing keys"
type T2 = CheckMissing<["p1", "p2"], { p1: any, p2: any }> // ["p1", "p2"]
```

Note: `T & "Error: missing keys"` is just for nice IDE errors. You could also write `never`. `CheckDuplicates` checks double tuple items:

```
type CheckDuplicate<T extends readonly any[]> = {
    [P1 in keyof T]: "_flag_" extends
    { [P2 in keyof T]: P2 extends P1 ? never :
        T[P2] extends T[P1] ? "_flag_" : never }[keyof T] ?
    [T[P1], "Error: duplicate"] : T[P1]
}

type T3 = CheckDuplicate<[1, 2, 3]> // [1, 2, 3]
type T4 = CheckDuplicate<[1, 2, 1]> 
// [[1, "Error: duplicate"], 2, [1, "Error: duplicate"]]
```

Note: More infos on unique item checks in tuples are in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57016728/is-there-a-way-to-define-type-for-array-with-unique-items-in-typescript). With [TS 4.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/), we also can name missing keys in the error string - take a look at [this Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=next#code/PTAEBUGVQFgOgIygEYFMAu7UCdQFsBLAZyIIDsBzUArPUAE2IAcAbAQwE8AoL1ADyYB7bOmpks2AGZsAxqlABJALIdwbZC3kBvLqD3V6ALlBkArnjTYA3Lv3oam40XTZyFG-tAzsqNlnoAgujGACJ+qB76xCGomv7GyIKCmmxkNgC+POgcTPIAwgAWqDIA1krEpJQAPOCg-Fhk9ESgqRwA2gC6ADSgAKp1fA1NoABKxcL0Vc6ulD2tAHzzoAC8oDqebQDSYqAlqByCkn0dxtv1qI3N4G1mFjgdoAD8JqgAbjigp1zpbXsHR70HudLmJJB8FLY9M82gogYMLsMbm97k8IJ80QAyUAAAwAothsMJjAByAAkWgUoCx0zc6WJ+AqbmxkPRZGR2CyOXyRVKIVMrAIMnCNQGQ2aPjY9EEZBYHBaZHaHSWq3W+jaAAUkORdvtDhATqAAEQAfUk7AoxsNooRRBZWlAGoATDs-nrwAb1c7gcNNai2e9cIYWZ5rp64WKIBqEA9niazWwLVbjP6Pj9XUd3U8WW1Q9Geob8YTsMZ6PyWILwoaHsZcx1vjx6MV2D5QJJTGQZPZpa2yCLveLfFKZXKABTpxQqNQaVAASk6oAAPg7x8pVOpNEqR8FMaBCsUyozquAequp5olli97yyxWsDV5jOazwQFwQKAABKCAOgL8fHBF0AihbdBBFAIhUHkNh8GEeQiFMGhUHoOoCWEfBUBIBN5AAdxoAoGRINwdTlYloliDBEOJV9gC4SQyBHNpDQIehDXzex0E0FijW8Xx-CCKsZx4HhaPoxjmNYhxUE4w1uPCQJ0Ck0i4kQ-jQBouiGIAR1MPh+LUkSmKktiOPzGTePk-NFPIsSjQMjoZyAA).

---

### Variant 3: Recursive type

With version 4.1, TypeScript officially supports [conditional recursive types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002), which can be potentially used here as well. Though, the type computation is expensive due to combinatory complexity - performance degrades massively for more than 5-6 items. I list this alternative for completeness ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=next#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFkBPAFUwCMAbPAbwCg5EATALjiQFcBbCtAbkZwYCGDXYBnGFGQBzQU2xRgmVMwCCMdgBFVwBYgnbgNNewoQINTEkEBfevRjEweAArLXSZgB5SAGjgAVThQVG8JOBtiAG0AXQA%20OABeOBiAuAA6bKC4uAB6fLh1ZmZEVG44UmEIOClMWDgIdGFOMBpguAAKUgBlOAAWTIAGOAA3BoRMZgRsVvbgCQBKR2dXOABpYGIJP1CQcOZIgCVgbGhfKRkkWUDohKTUrZ2AfT9A%20ISnFzxniTfqmFgBE4KdzlBLtI5HckMQEoEQkCQR4IK5YMRnp8UkIGEwmDE3IgkHAANbbZpVOLsWh2faHSIAeW4onecDcSQA-Gk3Hl2B5gF5fG5An83kyWRl2QiHkI7DEycQKaQ4o5zkgpMIAIzsP4%20IhkSg0R5pABEShUak0JsCJoQRhMwDU1rgtuYzpNIjEwBNeUKcEAKOT0NUamAAJh1212%20vI1GAxpiZuUeg0MHdduMpmAbptCGzLs9NHdCtDPoKRUAaOSk7aawxwZkSCRyIMQdXwGAAZgjOz1JBjRpSpvNyatOftmbzrvd6Espb9lentTtHFqCubreEAy7Ud7hrjA4TQ8tqdHGcdWbTE4L3ptxaL1anM99FfmHRgljgVBbsiAA)):

```
type Prepend<T, U extends any[]> = [T, ...U] // TS 4.0 variadic tuples

type Keys<T extends Record<string, any>> = Keys_<T, []>
type Keys_<T extends Record<string, any>, U extends PropertyKey[]> =
  {
    [P in keyof T]: {} extends Omit<T, P> ? [P] : Prepend<P, Keys_<Omit<T, P>, U>>
  }[keyof T]

const t1: Keys<IMyTable> = ["createdAt", "isDeleted", "id", "title"] // ✔
```

`+` tuple `+-` manual with auto-completion `+` no helper function `--` performance

---

### Variant 4: Code generator / TS compiler API

[ts-morph](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph) is chosen here, as it is a tad simpler wrapper alternative to the [original TS compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API). Of course, you can also use the compiler API directly. Let's look at the generator code:

```
// ./src/mybuildstep.ts
import {Project, VariableDeclarationKind, InterfaceDeclaration } from "ts-morph";

const project = new Project();
// source file with IMyTable interface
const sourceFile = project.addSourceFileAtPath("./src/IMyTable.ts"); 
// target file to write the keys string array to
const destFile = project.createSourceFile("./src/generated/IMyTable-keys.ts", "", {
  overwrite: true // overwrite if exists
}); 

function createKeys(node: InterfaceDeclaration) {
  const allKeys = node.getProperties().map(p => p.getName());
  destFile.addVariableStatement({
    declarationKind: VariableDeclarationKind.Const,
    declarations: [{
        name: "keys",
        initializer: writer =>
          writer.write(`${JSON.stringify(allKeys)} as const`)
    }]
  });
}

createKeys(sourceFile.getInterface("IMyTable")!);
destFile.saveSync(); // flush all changes and write to disk
```

After we compile and run this file with `tsc && node dist/mybuildstep.js`, a file `./src/generated/IMyTable-keys.ts` with following content is generated:

```
// ./src/generated/IMyTable-keys.ts
const keys = ["id","title","createdAt","isDeleted"] as const;
```

`+` auto-generating solution `+` scalable for multiple properties `+` no helper function `+` tuple `-` extra build-step `-` needs familiarity with compiler API

Comment: Looks like variant 1 doesn't do any work because I'll have to type out the whole keys in createKeys.

Comment: Variant 1 still statically enforces the resulting array to be complete. That said, I struggle to make variant 2 generic over `U` instead of `IMyTable`.

Answer (score 25):

This should work

```
var IMyTable: Array<keyof IMyTable> = ["id", "title", "createdAt", "isDeleted"];
```

or

```
var IMyTable: (keyof IMyTable)[] = ["id", "title", "createdAt", "isDeleted"];
```

Comment: Not that it's wrong, but to be clear here you are just "enforcing the values of the array" to be correct.  The developer still needs to write them down twice, manually.

Comment: This won't prevent key duplicates or missing keys. Like `var IMyTable: Array<keyof IMyTable> = ["id", "createdAt", "id"];`

Answer (score 17):

Instead of defining `IMyTable` as in interface, try defining it as a class.  In typescript you can use a class like an interface.

So for your example, define/generate your class like this:

```
export class IMyTable {
    constructor(
        public id = '',
        public title = '',
        public createdAt: Date = null,
        public isDeleted = false
    )
}
```

Use it as an interface:

```
export class SomeTable implements IMyTable {
    ...
}
```

Get keys:

```
const keys = Object.keys(new IMyTable());
```

Answer (score 6):

You will need to make a class that implements your interface, instantiate it and then use `Object.keys(yourObject)` to get the properties.

```
export class YourClass implements IMyTable {
    ...
}
```

then

```
let yourObject:YourClass = new YourClass();
Object.keys(yourObject).forEach((...) => { ... });
```

Comment: Doesn't work in my case, i'd have to list those properties of the interface but that is not what i want? Name of interface comes dynamically and then i've to determine its properties

Comment: This produces an error (v2.8.3): `Cannot extend an interface […]. Did you mean 'implements'?` However, using `implements` instead requires manually copying the interface, which is exactly what I don't want.

Comment: @jacob sorry, it should have been `implements` and I have updated my answer. As @basarat has stated, interfaces don't exist at runtime so the only way is to implement it as a class.

Comment: You mean instead of an interface use a class? Unfortunately I cannot as the interface comes from a 3rd-party (`@types/react`). I manually copied them, but that's hardly future-proof  I'm trying to dynamically bind non-lifecycle methods (which are already bound), but they're not declared on React.Component (the class).

Comment: No, I mean create a class that implements your 3rd party interface and get the properties of that class at runtime.

Comment: @DanDef that does not work: The implementing class has no properties and `Object.keys` returns an empty array. When the methods are not optional (moot point because they are in the 3rd-party interface), it causes a `Class incorrectly implements interface.` error https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20ISome%20%7B%0D%0A%09methodA%3F(foo%3A%20any)%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09methodB%3F(qux%3A%20any)%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Some%20implements%20ISome%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aconst%20someMethods%20%3D%20Object.keys(new%20Some)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(someMethods)%3B

Answer (score 5):

#### This was a tough one!  Thank you, everyone, for your assistance.

My need was to get keys of an interface as an array of strings to simplify mocha/chai scripting.  Not concerned about using in the app (yet), so didn't need the ts files to be created.  Thanks to [ford04](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5669456/ford04) for the assistance, his solution [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60932900/2957952) was a huge help and it works perfectly, NO compiler hacks.  Here's the modified code:

#### Option 2: Code generator based on TS compiler API (ts-morph)

#### Node Module

```
npm install --save-dev ts-morph
```

#### keys.ts

**NOTE**:  this assumes all ts files are located in the root of ./src and there are no subfolders, adjust accordingly

```
import {
  Project,
  VariableDeclarationKind,
  InterfaceDeclaration,
} from "ts-morph";

// initName is name of the interface file below the root, ./src is considered the root
const Keys = (intName: string): string[] => {
  const project = new Project();
  const sourceFile = project.addSourceFileAtPath(`./src/${intName}.ts`);
  const node = sourceFile.getInterface(intName)!;
  const allKeys = node.getProperties().map((p) => p.getName());

  return allKeys;
};

export default Keys;
```

#### usage

```
import keys from "./keys";

const myKeys = keys("MyInterface") //ts file name without extension

console.log(myKeys)
```

Answer (score 5):

Some people have suggested this, which has the benefit of being the most simple solution:

```
const properties: (keyof IMyTable)[] = ["id", "title", "createdAt", "isDeleted"];
```

However while this adds some type-safety (we cannot use non-existing properties by mistake), it is not a fully safe solution because we could miss some properties and have duplicates. So I have fixed that, this verbose solution is fully type-safe and prevents inconsistencies between the compile-time types and the run-time values of the array:

```
const properties: [
    keyof Pick<IMyTable, 'id'>,
    keyof Pick<IMyTable, 'title'>,
    keyof Pick<IMyTable, 'createdAt'>,
    keyof Pick<IMyTable, 'isDeleted'>
] = ['id', 'title', 'createdAt', 'isDeleted'];
```

Of course this is only applicable if you are fine with NOT avoiding the repetition, but at least you only have to be sure that you write all properties correctly once (on the Pick type util), and the rest will always raise an error if there's any mistake. I think it's the most robust solution among the simple, easy to understand and readable solutions.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't use a custom transformer (or prefer not to), I think the best way is what I'm about to show, which has the following advantages:

1. it allows for "semi-automatic" population of the array (at least in VS Code);
2. it results in an array that TypeScript recognizes as having elements that are a union of the interface's keys;
3. it doesn't involve performance-degrading recursive tricks.

Here is the approach:

```
interface Foo {
  fizz?: string;
  buzz: number;
}

const FooKeysEnum: { [K in keyof Required<Foo>]: K } = {
  fizz: 'fizz',
  buzz: 'buzz',
};

const FooKeys = Object.values(FooKeysEnum);
```

The "semi-automatic" population of the array in VS Code comes from the fact that when `FooKeysEnum` has a red underline because it's missing properties, you can hover over it and select "Add missing properties" from the "Quick Fix" menu. (This benefit is shared by other approaches already shown in this thread, but I don't think anyone had mentioned it yet. ETA: I was mistaken here; auto-completion has been mentioned elsewhere in the thread.)

Finally, by using `Object.values()` instead of `Object.keys()` to create the array, you get TypeScript to recognize that `FooKeys` has the type `("fizz" | "buzz")[]`. It doesn't know that `FooKeys[0]` is `"fizz"` and that `FooKeys[1]` is `"buzz"`, but still, better than the `string[]` you get with `Object.keys()`.

EDIT:

In VS Code, you can also set up a keyboard shortcut in `keybindings.json` for *executing* a "Quick Fix," which makes it even quicker to trigger `Add missing properties`. Would look something like this:

```
{
  "key": "shift+cmd+a",
  "command": "editor.action.codeAction",
  "args": {
    "kind": "quickfix",
    "apply": "ifSingle"
  }
}
```

Then if something's got a red underline, you can click it and use the keyboard-shortcut, and if there's only one quick-fix option available then it will run. Would be great if there were a way to target *specific* quick-fixes, and even better if it could be done automatically on file-save, but I don't think that's possible at the time of writing.

Answer (score 4):

As others have already said, the types are not available at runtime, so you need to either generate them or write by hand.

If you write them by hand, then the simple `Array<keyof IMyTable>` does not verify missing keys.

[Here is a really great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53395649/4420543) that answers the problem of declaring the array of keys with type safety. (Credit goes to him.) Relevant code:

```js
export interface IMyTable {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    createdAt: Date;
    isDeleted: boolean;
}

type Invalid<T> = ['Needs to be all of', T];
const arrayOfAll =
    <T>() =>
    <U extends T[]>(
        ...array: U & ([T] extends [U[number]] ? unknown : Invalid<T>[])
    ) =>
        array;

const fields = arrayOfAll<keyof IMyTable>()(
    'id',
    'createdAt',
    'title',
    'isDeleted',
);
```

If there were missing fields, an error would be shown.

Comment: This doesn't avoid duplicate entries in the array.

Answer (score 3):

In this [blog](https://steveholgado.com/typescript-types-from-arrays/)

**Getting a type from our array**

Now we can get a type from our animals array using typeof:

```js
const animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse'] as const
type Animal = typeof animals[number]

// type Animal = 'cat' | 'dog' | 'mouse'
```

Comment: OP wants an array of values, not a type.

Comment: The question was to get the other way around. Have a type (interface) and get an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using the:
`export type TableTypeKeys = (keyof TableType)[];`
option.

Here's a `ConfigService` that can be called using `ConfigService.getConfig()` and will throw an error if the env vars don't exist.

```js
export type Config = {
    YOUR_ENV_VAR: string;
}
export type EnvVar = (keyof Config)
export type EnvVarDefaultValue = string;

export class ConfigService {
    public static getConfig(): Config {
        const env = process.env
        const defaults: Record<EnvVar, EnvVarDefaultValue>  = {
            YOUR_ENV_VAR: "" // empty if there is no default and it is a required env var
        }
        Object.entries(defaults).forEach(([e, defaultValue]) => {
            if (defaultValue) 
                console.log(`Using default for ${e}=${defaultValue}`)
            if (!defaultValue && !env[e]) 
                throw Error(`Missing environment variable '${e}'` )
        })
        // We know at this point the env vars exist, so type assertion is fine.
        return env as Config
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that types are not available at runtime.  I ended up defining an object and deriving the type from that object.  You still get type support and gain the ability to get a list of keys all from a single place.

```
const myTable =  {
  id: 0,
  title: '',
  createdAt: null as Date,
  isDeleted: false,
};

export type TableType = typeof myTable;
export type TableTypeKeys = (keyof TableType)[];
export const tableKeys: TableTypeKeys = Object.keys(
  myTable
) as TableTypeKeys;
```

Implicit types resulting from above will be (you can check with VSCode or another quality IDE):

```
type TableType = {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    createdAt: Date;
    isDeleted: boolean;
}

type TableTypeKeys = ("id" | "title" | "createdAt" | "isDeleted")[]
```

and at runtime you'll be able to access the tableKeys array

```
console.log(tableKeys);
// output: ["id" , "title" , "createdAt" , "isDeleted"]
```

Answer (score -3):

just do this :

```
 export interface IMyTable {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  isDeleted: boolean;
}
const myVal: (keyof IMyTable)[] = ["id", "title", "createdAt", "isDeleted"];
```

It works great for me !

Answer (score -4):

Can't. Interfaces don't exist at runtime.

**A workaround**:

Create a variable of the type and use `Object.keys` on it

Comment: Do you mean like this: `var abc: IMyTable = {}; Object.keys(abc).forEach((key) => {console.log(key)});`

Comment: Nope, because that object has no keys on it. An interface is something that TypeScript uses but evaporates in the JavaScript, so there's no information left to inform any "reflection" or "interspection". All JavaScript knows is that there's an empty object literal. Your only hope is to wait for (or [request that](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues)) TypeScript includes a way to generate an array or object with all the keys in the interface into the source code. Or, as Dan Def says, if you can use a class, you will have the keys defined in the form of properties in every instance..

Comment: You would also get an error by TypeScript on this line: `var abc: IMyTable = {}` because the empty object literal does not conform to the shape of that interface.

Comment: If this does not work, why there are upvotes on this answer?

Comment: Well, there are upvotes because it works, indeed. `var abc: IMyTable = {};` produces a compilation error if `IMyTable` contains any key. So you have to insert all the keys required by the `IMyTable` in the object literal. The only (possible) drawback is that you could insert extra keys and TypeScript would not really complain.

Comment: downvote reason: no mention that it does not work for nullable values

Comment: It's ultimately not a great solution because you have to supply values. Probably better off just keeping a list of keys.

Comment: This doesn't work for interfaces as the question asks. Optional keys in the interface will not be instantiated, meaning this won't have _all_ values.

Answer (score -9):

```
// declarations.d.ts
export interface IMyTable {
      id: number;
      title: string;
      createdAt: Date;
      isDeleted: boolean
}
declare var Tes: IMyTable;
// call in annother page
console.log(Tes.id);
```

Comment: This code will not work as the typescript syntax is not available on run-time. If you check this code on typescript playground then you'll notice that the only thing that compiles to JavaScript is `console.log(Tes.id)` which of course would be error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Tes is not defined'