# Typescript: Visualize type, i.e. show type's signature

Tags: typescript

When we want to see *variable's* value, we just do `console.log(someVar)`

What about if we want to see what is there behind a *type*?

Example:

```
type SomeUnion = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'

console.log(SomeUnion) 
// of course above will not work, but what will do?
// is there any TS tool that I am missing?
```

P.S. For those who might not understand why would one need this, here is much more complex type (from [TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)):

```
type FunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]:
T[K] extends Function ? K : never }[keyof T];

interface Part {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    subparts: Part[];
    updatePart(newName: string): void;
}

type T40 = FunctionPropertyNames<Part>;  // "updatePart"
```

The last line has comment with what the type looks like. Currently what am I doing to find out if it really looks like this is something like:

```
let foo: T40 = 'bar' // gives error: type "bar" is not assignable to type "updatePart"
```

In other words, the only way to know what is hidden behind the type identifier is to generate a type error, which should not be the only way to do it.

Comment: I don't think there is any tool that will do this statically, but you can try to do an instance of the object and call Object.keys() on that. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43910186/1486848

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) ([current caveat](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26068)) or an IDE such as Visual Studio Code that supports the TypeScript language service, you can just hover over the `T40` in `type T40 = FunctionPropertyNames<Part>;` to see the expansion of the type.

Comment: Mostly, sometimes, for some types .... It works in this case but it's been my experience that the type is not always fully expanded, still better then nothing :)