# How to ensure an array's values the keys of a typescript interface?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to produce an `events` property on `Klass` which contains an array of strings that exactly matches all the keys of a given interface. Like so:

```
interface Events {
    one: (foo: string) => void
    two: (bar: number) => void
}

class Klass {
    protected readonly events: [keyof Events] = ['one', 'two']
}
```

However, the above errors out with the following:

```
[ts]
Type '["one", "two"]' is not assignable to type '["one" | "two"]'.
  Types of property 'length' are incompatible.
    Type '2' is not assignable to type '1'. [2322]
(property) Klass.events: ["one" | "two"]
```

What is needed here to ensure that the `events` property returns an array that contains all of the events?

Comment: protected readonly events: Array<keyof Events> = ['one', 'two']

Comment: @JBNizet unfortunately, that makes `['one']` is valid. Requirement is that the array must contain all of the keys, not just any of them.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I don't have any idea then. Not sure it's even possible.

Answer (score 16):

You can almost express this in the type system (assuming TS3.0+) with [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types), with a few caveats:

```
type Invalid<T> = ["Needs to be all of", T]
const arrayOfAll = <T>() => <U extends T[]>(
  ...array: U & ([T] extends [U[number]] ? unknown : Invalid<T>[])
) => array;
const arrayOfAllEventKeys = arrayOfAll<keyof Events>();

const goodEvents = arrayOfAllEventKeys('one', 'two'); // okay, type ['one', 'two']

const extraEvents = arrayOfAllEventKeys('one', 'two', 'three'); // error
//                                                    ~~~~~~~ 
// Argument of type "three" is not assignable to parameter of type "one" | "two"

const missingEvents = arrayOfAllEventKeys('one'); // error
//                                        ~~~~~ 
// Argument of type "one" is not assignable to 
// parameter of type ["Needs to be all of", "one" | "two"]

const redundantEvents = arrayOfAllEventKeys('one', 'two', 'one'); // no error
// doesn't enforce distinctness
```

Note that `goodEvents` is inferred to be of type `['one', 'two']`, and there is no error.  That's what you want.  You get errors on extra events and on missing events.

Caveat 1: The error for missing events is a bit cryptic; TypeScript doesn't yet support [custom error messages](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689), so I chose something that hopefully is somewhat understandable (`Argument of type "one" is not assignable to parameter of type ["Needs to be all of", "one" | "two"]`).

Caveat 2: There is no error for redundant events.  There's no general way that I can find to require that each parameter to `arrayOfAllEventKeys` is of a distinct type that doesn't run afoul of some [issues with recursive types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980).  It's possible to use overloading or other similar techniques to work for arrays of up to some hardcoded length (say, 10), but I don't know if that would meet your needs.  Let me know.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Pls help me out. What does `[T] extends [U[number]` mean? I've found out that `T extends U[number]` means pretty much the same thing, except it shows no error when a key is missing. The former one must be probably saying `array of a single T item extends an array where the first item can be any key that is indexed by a number of type U`, but that does not explain to me why the array notation is needed. (I suppose that this is an array, because `[T, number] extends [U[number], number]` works just like your version. So I may have asked this already earlier, but what is it called? Thanks so much.

Comment: `type F<T> = T extends U ? X : Y` and `type G<T> = [T] extends [U] ? X : Y` differ only in that `F` is a [distributive](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#distributive-conditional-types) conditional type, and `G` is not.  In `F`, `T` is a [naked type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55383816/2887218) but in `G` it is "clothed" in a [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Covariant_arrays_in_Java_and_C#) one-element [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple).

Answer (score 4):

You are putting the [] in the wrong place.

```
interface Events {
  one: (foo: string) => void
  two: (bar: number) => void
}

class Klass {
  protected readonly events: (keyof Events)[] = ['one', 'two']
}
```

Notice how I change `[keyof Events]` to `(keyof Events)[]`.

Check [this typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=8&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIDcLgM7IN4CwAUMqcgPYgQBcyAFDOebdmFKAOYCUyAvAHzJ05YABNiZZGADuzegCM4UWiACuAW3nQeAoSPFEAvsWIIANnGy4A0hav4JZAA5RykBJFHIoEOKMpmAJ7IEJg4tHQA1hCB5DBoYWDYXADaALp8yCkA5JQQ2QA0yNky5NlpxMZEJtVEQA) to verify that there are no errors.

Comment: The OP wants to ensure the array has ALL of the keys. If you remove `two` from your array, it won't throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a concrete object to achieve your goal here. In the example below, the implementation of the interface gives you a guaranteed way to get the right list. If you add a new member to `Events` it will force you to add it to `ConcreteEvents`. The only potential issue would be if you add other members to `ConcreteEvents`.

```
interface Events {
    one: (foo: string) => void;
    two: (bar: number) => void;
}

class ConcreteEvents implements Events {
    // Note! Only add members of Events
    one(foo: string) { };
    two(bar: number) { };
}

class Klass {
    public readonly events = Object.keys(ConcreteEvents.prototype) as any as [keyof Events][];
}

const klass = new Klass();
console.log(klass.events);
```

You could achieve this in several different ways using a concrete class or an object, so you don't have to follow this example exactly.

Comment: Brilliant. I'll give it a go tomorrow and will see what I can come up with.