# Why is a distributive conditional type with a generic called with a type argument not the same as the non-generic version of this type?

Tags: typescript

```
// false
type BasicType = (string | number) extends string ? true : false;


// P is boolean
type Parameterized<T> = T extends string ? true : false;
type P = Parameterized<string | number>
```

How come types `P` and `BasicType` aren't the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript Distributive Conditional Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382306/typescript-distributive-conditional-types)

Comment: The behavior you're mentioning is documented (as described in the answer to the linked question): conditional types are only distributive if the type being checked is a bare generic type parameter.  `(string | number)` is not a generic type parameter, so it's not distributive.  Does the other answer suffice for your question?  When you say "how come" you could be asking for documentation (which is the other q), or you could be asking *why* they implemented it like this instead of another way... I don't think I can answer that *definitively* but it would be a different question at least.

Comment: Thanks I had read that part of the docs multiple times but hadn't made the connection