# What does it mean for a type to distribute over unions?

Tags: typescript, types, theory, union-types, conditional-types

I'm reading an article :["Unionize and Objectify: A Trick for Applying Conditional Types to Objects"](https://effectivetypescript.com/2020/05/12/unionize-objectify/?utm_source=typescript-weekly.com&utm_campaign=typescript_weekly_138&utm_medium=email)

> In TypeScript our most powerful tool is conditional types. This is
>   because they have two unique abilities:
>
> - They distribute over unions.
> - They enable you to use the infer keyword.

What does 'distribute over unions' mean in general and in this context?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript Distributive Conditional Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382306/typescript-distributive-conditional-types)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The term *distributive* refers to how union types should be treated when subjected to type-level operations (such as `keyof` or mapped types).

- **Non-distributive (default)** operations are applied to properties that exist on every member of the union.
- **Distributive** operations are applied to *all members* of the union separately.

Let's use an example.

```
type Fruit =
  | { species: 'banana', curvature: number }
  | { species: 'apple', color: string }
```

Let's assume that, for some reason, you want to know all possible keys that can exist on a `Fruit`.

**Non-distributive**

Your intuition may tell you to do:

```
type KeyOfFruit = keyof Fruit; // "species"
```

However, this will give you only the properties that exist on every member of the union. In our example, `species` is the only common property shared by all `Fruit`.

It's the same as applying `keyof` to the union of the two types.

```
keyof ({ species: 'banana', curvature: number } | { species: 'apple', color: string })
```

**Distributive**

With distribution, the operation is not performed on *just* the common properties. Instead, it is done on *every member of the union separately*. The results are then added together.

```
type DistributedKeyOf<T> =
  T extends any
    ? keyof T
    : never

type KeyOfFruit = DistributedKeyOf<Fruit>; // "species" | "curvature" | "color"
```

In this case, TypeScript applied `keyof` to each member of the union, and summed the results.

```
keyof { species: 'banana', curvature: number } | keyof { species: 'apple', color: string }
```

Comment: FWIW one might want to see [the Handbook documentation for distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)