# Why ts-toolbelt library use "O extends unknown" expression

Tags: typescript

I am studying the source code of the ts-toolbelt library.
And I often meet this expression`O extends unknown`. In my opinion, it does not add any functionality.

And so I wondered, what is it for?

````
/**
 * @hidden
 */
export type _UnionOf<O extends object> =
    O[keyof O]

/**
 * Transform an [[Object]] into an [[Union]]
 * @param O to transform
 * @returns [[Any]]
 * @example
 * ```ts
 * ```
 */
export type UnionOf<O extends object> =
    O extends unknown
    ? _UnionOf<O>
    : never
````

For some reason, instead of exporting the `_UnionOf` type, it is preceded by the expression `O extends unknown`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably the library authors decided that `UnionOf<A | B | C>` should produce the same result as `UnionOf<A> | UnionOf<B> | UnionOf<C>`, and the definition of `_UnionOf` did not do that.  The `O extends unknown ? ... : never` check, which deceptively looks like it does nothing, causes that to happen.

Expressions that look like they do nothing but actually distribute across unions, when `T` is a generic type parameter:

- `T extends unknown ? ... : never`
- `T extends any ? ... : never`
- `T extends T ? ... : never`

---

If `T` is a *type parameter*, as in the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function `function foo<T>(/*...*/): void` or the generic interface `interface Foo<T> {/*...*/}`, then a type of the form `T extends XXX ? YYY : ZZZ` is a [*distributive* conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).

It *distributes* the conditional check across [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in `T`.  When `T` is specified with some specific type, the compiler splits that type up into its union members, evaluates the check for each such member, and then joins the results back into a new union.  So if `F<T>` distributes across unions, then `F<A | B | C>` will be the same as `F<A> | F<B> | F<C>`.

---

Not all type functions are distributive across unions.  For example, [the `keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) does not turn unions of inputs into unions of outputs:

```
type KeyofA = keyof {a: string}; // "a"
type KeyofB = keyof {b: number}; // "b"
type KeyofAorB = keyof ({ a: string } | { b: number }); // never
```

Similarly, `_UnionOf` is not distributive across unions (related to the fact that it uses `keyof` in its definition):

```
type Oops = _UnionOf<{ a: string } | { b: number }>
// never
```

If you have a type function which is *not* distributive in unions and you *want* it to be, you can wrap it in a distributive conditional type:

```
type DistribKeyof<T> = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never;

type UnionKeyofAorB = DistribKeyof<{ a: string } | { b: number }>; // "a" | "b"
```

And therefore `UnionOf` *is* distributive across unions:

```
type Correct = UnionOf<{ a: string } | { b: number }>
// string | number
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIHsBmBBKBeKBreyoG8oBDALigGdgAnASwDsBzKAXwG4oB6DqAIiJ4BQoSLFxIAQhmxiCUAEZk6AVwC2ciFRbsuvOYOHQ4iVAiqTMOY1AAUhUhWr0mzKAB9ZCqMrUaWASm1uOggANw0BIXBoABEaSlo5I2QAHgAVAD4pVKgIAA9gCDoAE3IoJTosOgQAdzooAH5pK2zFUI1WCIMoAFU6GgQ6JJMzKVj4mkSxZLsyccYWNw9FVXVNZnTA3n5Fnj0IjgAqA4EoA6gAAQALGiKiwpODjgE8sFNgKC6AfV7+ugB5JDJP45fKFEpQBByABWEAAxsBMugTlAUX8ANqWPB-AC6+yODygqSoRDo5CQphUxDqaLRf2hcOA2OxUHowAQVKgNJ+AyZBPOYCIxMpwLZH2JpPJVBUfKoEGASiopM5aJQdBAvNOFzyRBUYAANhACQADE3AcjGk0PJ4vN4fKI9PoDAFAkEFYqlSEw+GI5Go11g0rlSo1Oi+hpQb6O-6Av7pMOtMJUCKREQAYVMsvhUm50emxFmjnmLnchE83lWLDjOjmTHc5fCKegfwQYFKmEjv2dMwctCLi1Lyx8ayrQTaVCAA)

Answer (score 2):

`O extends unknown ? _UnionOf<O> : never` is a [*conditional type*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html); here it is used as a [*distributive conditional type*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). Without using a conditional type, TypeScript will narrow the type to one that applies to all possible union values (often `never`). With distributive conditional types, it will apply to each potential union value. Though the conditional aspect of distributive conditional types could be used to filter the potential union values, here that is unnecessary, so you'll frequently see values like `T extends any` (as in the handbook) or `T extends unknown` here.

As for the difference between those, *dragomirtitian* describes it in the [Typescript gitter.im](https://gitter.im/Microsoft/TypeScript?at=5d66521b07d1ff39f899520c):

> `any` sometimes deletes information about the type parameter. There was a bug around this I filed myself [microsoft/TypeScript#30569](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30569). It should work ok now, but I would still recommend one of the other two ways [ed: `T extends unknown` or `T extends T`]. Any extends clause in a conditional type introduces information about `T`, `extends any` can confuse the compiler about `T`

See also:

- [What does it mean for a type to distribute over unions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62084836/what-does-it-mean-for-a-type-to-distribute-over-unions)
- [Typescript Distributive Conditional Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382306/typescript-distributive-conditional-types)