# Why can't Typescript use a generic as a type guard?

Tags: typescript, narrowing

Here's an example of Typescript code that uses a generic to narrow down the possible input of a second parameter's value, depending on the first value:

```js
type DataMap = {
  A: { a: string };
  B: { b: string };
};

type Type = keyof DataMap;

type Data<TType extends Type> = DataMap[TType];

interface ItemOptions<TType extends Type> {
  data: Data<TType>;
  type: TType;
}

function Item<TType extends Type>({ type, data }: ItemOptions<TType>) {
  if (type === "A") {
    // Typescript error: Property 'a' does not exist on type '{ a: string; } | { b: string; }'.
    return data.a;
  }
  if (type === "B") {
    // Typescript error: Property 'b' does not exist on type '{ a: string; } | { b: string; }'.
    return data.b;
  }
}
```

The reason I'm confused about why this doesn't compile, is that it correctly identifies valid parameter values when calling the function:

```js
// This works
Item({ type: "B", data: { b: "" } });

// These don't compile
Item({ type: "B", data: { a: "" } });
Item({ type: "A", data: { b: "" } });
```

What is the reason for this, and what is a good way to solve this issue?

Comment: Technically it's correct to warn since `Item` can take a union as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/WKpJgw). The underlying issue is the mismatch between generics and control flow analysis and there have been various requests for improvements, like [ms/TS#33014](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014). How to solve the issue depends on your requirements, but the two general approaches are: make it all unions and control flow like [this](//tsplay.dev/WJAK6m), or all generic and distributive object types like [this](//tsplay.dev/wjDd6m). Which if any would you like to see written as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is when `TType` is `"A"|"B"`, type of `data` in `ItemOptions` is mixed (`Data<"A"|"B">`) instead of `Data<"A"> | Data<"B">`, here is an example:

```
const a = {} as ItemOptions<"A"|"B">
if(a.type) {
  // Typescript error: Property 'a' does not exist on type 'Data<"A" | "B">'.
  a.data.a
}
```

to resolve this, you will need a helper type

```
type ItemOptionsArg<TType extends Type> = TType extends TType ? ItemOptions<TType> : never
```

more explain about `TType extends TType`:
[Why ts-toolbelt library use "O extends unknown" expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69167148/why-ts-toolbelt-library-use-o-extends-unknown-expression)

the type `ItemOptionsArg` separate `ItemOptions` to union object, for example:
`ItemOptionsArg<"A"|"B">` truns to `ItemOptions<"A"> | ItemOptions<"B">`

and the function can be rewrite as the following: (I'm not sure why `if` doesn't works but `switch` does)

```
function Item<TType extends Type>({ type, data }: ItemOptionsArg<TType>) {
    switch (type) {
        case "A":
            return data.a
        case "B":
            return data.b
    }
}
```