# With Typescript, can I get the type of a value in an object in an array, based on the value of another key in the same object?

Tags: typescript

I got the following object:

```
const features = [{
  key: 'some-key',
  fallback: true
}, {
  key: 'another-key',
  fallback: 'a string'
}] as const;
```

As you can see, the fallback value can be different types.

Now I want a function to retrieve the value of a feature from an API. If there is none, it should return the fallback.

But I want the possibility to overwrite the fallback at some cases with my own. Then I need the type of the fallback, related to the 'selected' key.

Now, I get the list of possible keys in this way:

```
type FeatureKey = typeof features[number]['key'];
```

Then I create a function:

```
function getFeature(key: FeatureKey) {
  // Some API Call, but otherwise return fallback
  return features.find(feature => feature.key === key)?.fallback;
}
```

But I want to add an argument to overwrite the fallback for that moment:

```
function getFeature(key: FeatureKey, fallback: [TYPEOF FALLBACK BASED ON GIVEN KEY]) {
  // Some API Call, but otherwise return fallback
  return features.find(feature => feature.key === key)?.fallback;
}
```

My question is: is it possible to get the type of the fallback value, based on the given key name in the function?

So when I use `getFeature('some-key', [...])`, I have to give in a boolean als fallback argument. And when I use `getFeature('another-key', [...])`, I have to give in a string as fallback.

Comment: Why are the feature objects in an array? Is that the whole object shape in the array you've shown?

Comment: Yes it is (for now). Maybe I want to add some other stuff with dates or something else. But the idea is that I can add a new feature to this array easily and don't think about the rest :)

Comment: Any particular reason not to use an object instead of an array, keyed with the feature key?

Comment: Ah, you mean something like: `{ 'some-key': { fallback: true }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to widen the literal type in `features` first:

```
// you can tack on more types later
type Widen<T> = T extends string ? string : T extends number ? number : T extends boolean ? boolean : T;
```

then widen the fallback type based on the given key:

```
function getFeature<K extends FeatureKeys>(key: K, fallback?: Widen<Extract<typeof features[number], { key: K }>["fallback"]>) {
  return features.find(feature => feature.key === key)?.fallback ?? fallback;
}
```

You can also use a mapped type (like Jerry's answer) to simplify:

```
function getFeature<K extends FeatureKeys>(key: K, fallback?: Widen<FeatureMap[K]>) {
    return features.find((feature) => feature.key === key)?.fallback ?? fallback;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgUwIZQK4CcERgXhgbQCgYSYBvY0qgawQE8AuGAIghAFsEBaWu5gGkpUScJABsxAIyTBqTKOlQJBVAL4rSFYaV5NmSMCCgALBOh70BQ4aInTZepDGjoAlmADmVtYIC6MJGxQSCgAbkJCKDoABwQYADFkNEwAaXpsPAAKKNiQOHgkjCwASnwwVHZJM198Zl5mX3DImLiAdVcAEwQwAB4AFQA+XBg+mAQADyhujuwXdw8YAH5nBXmYJlGJqbAZmHLKsyW9iqr0dZGxyensSRAQMWQwI9v7x-O+prhUMGAoV3AYB4EFBEigij0UpdtrtQckEGk6BABpldDAUvx4OIpDJqIsmO0ur0AKKTdAyKA9bItPIFMGYCClfanXwYsgwVGQ1QDWq2bGyBoDYrkayYZJPRB0rAAOjg7g6mUyErhQpwQyVRSlvFwODwvGKixlWPs1CWy15xvCqgiQJBhUwmVYHG49QxtggCGK4RtsKKDrYnAsfAxABYAEyemAAekjMGkHUI3rtCAdBiMpnMLpYc08zE9CeBPvt+kMJjMgYEMDDEejsaQ8cIWlIOTihYQAFkkNFho3tPhIe4YFTcvl1fTGSdqgFsClavVfL4mDPmOacQ1wmomlQvj8-gDE5KIVDrgkkwikSj6IvXUacXiYATuj1Wx3on3fILhdoSKKMOKkxAZTlBVRw9XA1STTV6G1XV6H1Q07BxU1MQQ2R11IK0rSAA)

Comment: So actually it is not possible to dynamically get the type of the value? I'm just trying so set it up as dynamic as possible, but in this case I have to set explicit the types with the `Widen` type, right?

Comment: @R.GrootJebbink Yeah, it would be nice if we had an intrinsic `Widen` type, but for now, you will have to write it yourself. Unfortunately removing the `as const` would not work since then the keys would not be inferred as literal types.

Comment: Wauw, learning a lot. I like Typescript, but just know some basics of it. I will put my solution in a new answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to define their relationship first:

```
type FeatureMap = {
  [K in typeof features[number] as K["key"]]:K["fallback"]
}

type FeatureKey = keyof FeatureMap;
```

and declare the function with generic:

```
function getFeature<T extends FeatureKey>(key: T, fallback: FeatureMap[T])
```

note that the type of `fallback` parameter will be the same to the original object

> for example: when the `key` is `some-key`, `fallback` will be `true` instead of `boolean`

---

If the type of `fallback` need to be more "widen", I will suggest to
defined these types reversely. Create the `FeatureMap` first, then use it to create `features` object (if it still needed for other places):

```
interface FeatureMap {
  "some-key": boolean
  "another-key": string
}

type Feature<T extends FeatureKey = FeatureKey> = T extends T ? {
  key: T,
  fallback: FeatureMap[T]
} : never

const features: Feature[] = [{
  key: 'some-key',
  fallback: true
}, {
  key: 'another-key',
  fallback: 'a string'
}]
```

and here is some explains about `T extends T` just FYI: [Why ts-toolbelt library use "O extends unknown" expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69167148/why-ts-toolbelt-library-use-o-extends-unknown-expression)

Comment: Thank you. This is very very nice and very close. I still need one more thing. Actually I need the type of the value of fallback. So for now, I can only use `true` for `some-key`. But it should be a Boolean.
Is that possible? I tried `: typeof K["fallback"]` but that didn't work.

Comment: I see now that you already explained that in your answer. But is is possible to get the `boolean` type instead of `true`?

Comment: I am not sure your user serinao, but just update the answer with a solution that define the interface first

Comment: Well, I want to make feature toggles and feature values. And maybe later some more variants. So I thought, I will make one function to do that and infer the types, instead of using multiple functions. But for now, I think I will do that. It's a bit easier to manage and maybe even better for other colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above will fix my problem, but for now I've chosen for a more simple solution. Instead of creating one function `getFeature` to get booleans and / or strings, I will make two functions, specific for the type.

So I will create a `getFeatureToggle` function and a `getFeatureValue`. Then I will always know I have to use a boolean or a string.

Also for other programmers it's maybe better to understand which function to use and wat it does.