# TS Generic boolean type Result is weird

Tags: typescript, generics

I can not understand why Type A2 and A3`s result is not same.

```
type MyType<T extends unknown[], U> = U extends T[number] ? true : false; 
type A1 = MyType<[2,3,4],boolean> // false
type A2 = MyType<[2,true,3,4],boolean> // boolean
type A3 = boolean extends (2 | true | 3 | 4) ? true : false // false
```

I think A2 result should be `false` not the `boolean` also i think A2 will be translated into A3. but it`s not right. 
Here is my reason why i think result is false.

```
T = [2,true,3,4]
T[number] = 2 | true | 3 | 4

boolean extends 2 | true | 3 | 4 ? true : false
= false.
```

can you explain why A2 is boolean?

Thank you..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `type` in the form of `T extends U ? A : B`, the compiler will extract the `T` patameter and inference it [one by one](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).

So for `A2`, the type `boolean` will destruct to `true | false` and will become:

```
type Result = (true extends (2 | true | 3 | 4) ? true : false) | (false extends (2 | true | 3 | 4) ? true : false)
```

which is

```
type Result =  true | false
```

so the `Result` will be `boolean`

---

This is also a common used trick:

[Why ts-toolbelt library use "O extends unknown" expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69167148/why-ts-toolbelt-library-use-o-extends-unknown-expression)

Comment: thank you for ur answer. but i have a one more quesiton.

type MyType3<U,T> = U extends T ? true : false; 
type Z3 = MyType3<'a','a'|'b'> // true,

type Z3 is true, but according to your answer, it should be `boolean` because
('a' extends 'a') | ('a' extends 'b') => true | false => boolean
<br/>
i think union distributive in generic only applies to left-hand-side. (in T extends U, T is left-hand-side)

Comment: I think your answer is logical. But I'm confused because there's a counter-example.
<code>
type MyType3<U,T> = U extends T ? true : false; 
type Z3 = MyType3<'a','a'|'b'> // true
</code>

Comment: You are right, I just got mixed up the behavior. Answer edited.

Comment: wow.. really thank you!! now i understand how below code is works!!
<code>
type Z = MyType<[true,false], boolean> // true
type Z1 = MyType<[true], boolean> // boolean
</code>

by the way if `boolean` becomes `true|false`, i think `number` should be `0|1|2|3|4...` so 
<code>
type Z2 = MyType<[1,2,3],number> // false, 
</code>
i think Z2 should be `boolean` according to your answer. can you explain little bit more or get some references???

Comment: not 100% sure but I think `number` represent *all numbers* includes `1,2,3...` and `0.1,0.2,0.3,...` so it is not be able to transform to union form, that's why it does not be distributed, this also happened in `string` type

Comment: thankyou @Jerryh001 

I read about the distributive generics you gave me before, but I didn't think `boolean` was a `true | false` form of union. Thank you for giving me a good insight. I'll look for the rest of the questions for myself!

Comment: :) you are welcome, for `boolean is true | false`, try this one: `type ExtractUnion<T> = T extends T ? [T] : never; type Value = ExtractUnion<boolean>` the `Value` will become `[false] | [true]`, it shows that `boolean` can be distributed, but not for `number` or `string`