What are all of the exceptions to referential transparency in TypeScript generics?
I want to write a TypeScript type based on a union such that each member of the union is transformed a certain way if it matches a certain shape, and is otherwise discarded. In working on this, I found that in TypeScript, the result of applying a type to a generic is different than substituting that type into the body of the generic in place of the type parameter. For example:
type T = "a" | "b" | "c" | 1 | 2 | 3;
// type U = never
type U = T extends string ? T : never;
type GV<GT> = GT extends string ? GT : never;
// type V = "a" | "b" | "c"
type V = GV<T>;

Type U and V are different, even though substituting T into the body of GV in place of GT would yield exactly the definition of U.
The official documentation for generics makes no mention of the fact that applying a generic to a type does not behave the same as substituting the type in for the generic's parameter. The particular behavior with union types shown above is documented in a separate section, titled Distributive Conditional Types, but that page too does not indicate whether or not generics have other exceptions to referential transparency.
I would like to be able to use generics in TypeScript, but as shown above, there is at least one exception to what would otherwise seem like the way to think about their semantics. Are there other exceptions? Given that referential transparency is not an accurate way to think about the semantics of TypeScript generics, what is the intended way to think about them? Are they intended to be thought of as referentially transparent but with a known list of exceptions, or is an entirely different understanding intended?

I think the keywords you're looking for has to distributing over unions, or distributive conditional types. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62084836/what-does-it-mean-for-a-type-to-distribute-over-unions and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382306/typescript-distributive-conditional-types and https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types
