# Transforming an array to an object with key from common property in elements of array

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I have an object similar to this:

```
const v = [
  { pointer: "/name", name: "N1" },
  { pointer: "/name", name: "N2" },
  { pointer: "/zip", name: "Z1" }
] as const
```

and I'd like to generate objects like this:

```
const m: M = {
  "/name": [{ pointer: "/name", name: "N2" }] // can also contain N1, but not Z1
}
```

Is it possible to create a type for this? My attempt should better explain what I'm trying to do:

```
type V = typeof v;
type T = V[number]

type M = {
  [K in T["pointer"]]: Array<T extends {pointer: K} ? T : never>;
}
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/56564

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but the problem is that your `T` is a concrete type and not a generic type parameter, and thus `T extends { pointer: K } ? T : never` does not [distributive over unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).  So `T extends { pointer: K }` will just be false for each choice of `K`, and you get `never[]` instead of what you're looking for.

The easiest way to get distributive conditional types back is to use a type alias of the form `type Something<X> = X extends { pointer: K } ? X : never` and then plug in `Something<T>`.  Luckily, the built-in [`Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) already works this way.  So we can write this:

```
type M = { [K in T["pointer"]]?: Array<Extract<T, { pointer: K }>> };
```

which evaluates to:

```
/* 
type M = {
    "/name"?: ({
        readonly pointer: "/name";
        readonly name: "N1";
    } | {
        readonly pointer: "/name";
        readonly name: "N2";
    })[];
    "/zip"?: {
        readonly pointer: "/zip";
        readonly name: "Z1";
    }[];
}
*/
```

Which is closer to what you want, I think.  Note that I made the props optional, since your `m` constant doesn't have all the props:

```
const m: M = {
    "/name": [{ pointer: "/name", name: "N2" }]
}; // okay
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbjAvDA2gWAFA2zA3jABxAEswoBTAJwC4YAiAejAEMBbcugGhhfdroByARjowAvp0w48hEmSr8mbDt17l+AgEyiJUnPiKkKNegwBexAlx7L+ALRHjMAXRjMIMUJCgBuTJigATwJyGAAVJBgACiCQkAAzeABKFDAAV1YAIypnPwwA4NCAWUj8FABpGFJwlDpDeUo6Z2cAfloAQUpKZkCAHgBRAA8obuAoXrDuAzljWkqxAD4F8TzMBgAqGAKQmBLkXD1sRjU6NuiDrGkcSnJmABNwABtA2SMFUxO8q+vbh7Bnmx8ejCOhfHBiGAAHzwhyuN3uTxe9VmH2UoNh0nhfwBag02jB2DEKVysMYFisZwu32wWMRrwainJoK2l2+tP+L1x9Ac6NZ4hQJIwYkw6wY-gwXmgMFYtD2ML5xzRtBQ0zeJkV7GsXME2nEzkwYh8MAYDBgIAA1j0gA)

Comment: Can you explain why concrete types don't distribute over unions? As far as I can tell, `T` is a naked union type.

Comment: It’s not a generic type parameter so it doesn’t satisfy the requirements (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55383816/2887218) for more info).

Comment: Answer helped, but are you aware of any sort of reason why being a generic type parameter is a requirement?

Comment: [The PR implementing conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) doesn't say why it doesn't happen for non-generic unions.  Maybe [microsoft/TypeScript#30572](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30572) is of interest to you and you want to give it a ?