# Why this CustomExtract returns an different result from default Extract?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The code explains my question:

```
type A = {
  a: number,
} | null

// Extract as defined in lib.es5.d.ts
type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;

type CustomExtract = A extends null ? A : never;

type Result1 = Extract<A, null> // null
type Result2 = CustomExtract;   // never
```

Extract and CustomExtract are the same code, with the difference that Extract is a generic type.

Also, as related example, `string | null` does not extends `null`.

So, how types really works under the hoods at this topic? I can imagine it maybe runs the generic type for each type of the union and then unionize all the results, but I want the real technical definition and working of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that `Extract` is a [*distributive* conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), while your `CustomExtract` is not.

In order for a conditional type of the form `X extends Y ? A : B` to be distributive, the checked type `X` must be a "naked type parameter"; that is, a *type parameter* like `T` in `interface Foo<T> {...}`, and *naked* in that it is just the type parameter being checked (i.e., `T extends ...`) and not just some expression that includes the type parameter (e.g., `Promise<T> extends ...` or `[T] extends ...`).

As you surmised, distributive conditional types do indeed evaluate as the union of the conditional for each union element of the checked type `T`.  So if `F<T>` is a distributive conditional type, then `F<A | B | C>` will be evaluated as `F<A> | F<B> | F<C>`. One potential catch is that `F<never>` will be evaluated as `never` no matter what the details of `F` are (as long as it's distributive), as `never` is considered to be the ["empty union type"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23182#issuecomment-379094672).

For further information, see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55383816/2887218) about what distributive conditional types are and how they work.

Answer (score 4):

What @jcalz has said is all correct, but I'm going to try to put this is plain English.

What [`Extract<T, U>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) does is return the **subset** of `T` which is assignable to `U`.  If `T` has some `U` types and some other types, we get just the `U` types.  Why and how it does this, despite having a definition that looks the same as `CustomExtract`, that is @jcalz's answer.

In your case, `type A` is the union of `{a: number}` and `null`.  `{a: number}` is not assignable to `null`, but `null` is assignable to `null`.  So the subset which is assignable to `null` is `null`.

`type CustomExtract = A extends null ? A : never;` **will never return a subset**.  If the condition is met then it returns `A` in its entirety and if the condition is not met then it returns `never`.

In order for `X extends Y` to be true, all values of `X` must be assignable to `Y` or in other words, `X` must be equal to or narrower than `Y`.

`A extends null` is false because `A` is broader than `null`.  On the other hand, `null extends A` is true.