# typescript: Using infer with never get different result

Tags: typescript

I made a few demos to reproduce my problems. Here they are.

Question1: why does type `g` get `2`?

```
// 1
type f = [never] extends [infer S1, ...infer S2]
  ? ([S1] extends [never] ? 1 : 2)
  : 3
// why 2
type g = [never] extends [infer S1, ...infer S2]
  ? ([never] extends [S1] ? 1 : 2)
  : 3
```

From my perspective, type `f` equals `g` because `S1` is `never`.

Question2: why does type `h` get `2`?

```
// 1
type i = [never] extends [infer S1]
  ? ([never] extends [S1] ? 1 : 2)
  : 3
// why 2
type h = [never] extends [infer S1, ...infer S2]
  ? ([never] extends [S1] ? 1 : 2)
  : 3
```

From my perspective, type `i` equals `h` because `S2` is unused.

Question3: why does type `k` get `never`?

```
// 1
type j = [never] extends [infer S1, ...infer S2]
  ? (never extends S1 ? 1 : 2)
  : 3
// why never ?
type k = [never] extends [infer S1, ...infer S2]
  ? (S1 extends never ? 1 : 2)
  : 3
```

I couldn't understand even a little. I thought `k` should be one of `1` `2` `3` at least.

Comment: Question 1 and 2 seem like TypeScript bugs to me but I'm not sure until I have a chance to research it.  Type 3 is because `S1 extends never ? 1 : 2` is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) and `never` is treated as the "empty union": If `F<T | U>` is always equal to `F<T> | F<U>`, then you can show that `F<never>` should be `never` (or at least a subtype of every possible output of `F<T>`).  [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64250509/2887218).

Comment: I still haven't found anything concrete for #1 and #2.  If I don't find something you might want to file a bug with something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxo5XN) as your [mcve] of the issue.  Looks like whatever happened occurred between TS4.1 and TS4.2.  Looks like it's a variant of #42331 that wasn't fixed, maybe.

Answer (score 4):

Your questions 1 and 2 seem to be exposing a bug in TypeScript.

I also expect your `F`, `G`, `H`, and `I` types (non primitive types are conventionally written in UpperCamelCase and not lowerCamelCase, which makes them look like variable names) to evaluate to `1`.  The fact that `G` and `H` evaluate to `2` is surprising.  My research indicates that this behavior is new; you can verify that your code [works as expected in TypeScript 4.1.5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAyghgWwgHgCpQgD2BAdgEwGcoBVAGlI2zyKgDUK6oBeKVAPhagDcB7AS3wBuAFAjQkKADEuAbVwRuEAE4BdKjgLFZ-XADMVsAIwUAdOd0HlsAEzqA-FAAUsmEfVZNteYpUOoRlAAXFA2AJTBUADM4uDQAOJyCkpqGjTaloZuZhb6WXZQji7JfmlaUK7uhQGR4ZExsZIAkkm+qZ7pFZnWbv7FbR7U5ZX+gSF1ITES0AASrSmDXhl5PSZQ5qbdtn0+C2XevdVjoRGTYtNQAMIAFhAAxgDWUoms8EjIUhTx7KIXN-cPGYtV6IFAzChNH5iIA), but [fails in TypeScript 4.2.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAyghgWwgHgCpQgD2BAdgEwGcoBVAGlI2zyKgDUK6oBeKVAPhagDcB7AS3wBuAFAjQkKADEuAbVwRuEAE4BdKjgLFZ-XADMVsAIwUAdOd0HlsAEzqA-FAAUsmEfVZNteYpUOoRlAAXFA2AJTBUADM4uDQAOJyCkpqGjTaloZuZhb6WXZQji7JfmlaUK7uhQGR4ZExsZIAkkm+qZ7pFZnWbv7FbR7U5ZX+gSF1ITES0AASrSmDXhl5PSZQ5qbdtn0+C2XevdVjoRGTYtNQAMIAFhAAxgDWUoms8EjIUhTx7KIXN-cPGYtV6IFAzChNH5iIA).  Specifically, this change happened on or around January 12 or 13 of 2021.  Your code [works as expected in TypeScript 4.2.0-dev.20210112](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-dev.20210112#code/C4TwDgpgBAyghgWwgHgCpQgD2BAdgEwGcoBVAGlI2zyKgDUK6oBeKVAPhagDcB7AS3wBuAFAjQkKADEuAbVwRuEAE4BdKjgLFZ-XADMVsAIwUAdOd0HlsAEzqA-FAAUsmEfVZNteYpUOoRlAAXFA2AJTBUADM4uDQAOJyCkpqGjTaloZuZhb6WXZQji7JfmlaUK7uhQGR4ZExsZIAkkm+qZ7pFZnWbv7FbR7U5ZX+gSF1ITES0AASrSmDXhl5PSZQ5qbdtn0+C2XevdVjoRGTYtNQAMIAFhAAxgDWUoms8EjIUhTx7KIXN-cPGYtV6IFAzChNH5iIA), but [fails in TypeScript 4.2.0-dev.20210113](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-dev.20210113#code/C4TwDgpgBAyghgWwgHgCpQgD2BAdgEwGcoBVAGlI2zyKgDUK6oBeKVAPhagDcB7AS3wBuAFAjQkKADEuAbVwRuEAE4BdKjgLFZ-XADMVsAIwUAdOd0HlsAEzqA-FAAUsmEfVZNteYpUOoRlAAXFA2AJTBUADM4uDQAOJyCkpqGjTaloZuZhb6WXZQji7JfmlaUK7uhQGR4ZExsZIAkkm+qZ7pFZnWbv7FbR7U5ZX+gSF1ITES0AASrSmDXhl5PSZQ5qbdtn0+C2XevdVjoRGTYtNQAMIAFhAAxgDWUoms8EjIUhTx7KIXN-cPGYtV6IFAzChNH5iIA).

It seems very likely that this behavior was introduced when [microsoft/TypeScript#42248](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42248) was merged into the main code branch.  This pull request fixed a bug ([microsoft/TypeScript#39992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39992)) but seems to have caused a few new bugs, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#42331](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42331).

I have filed [microsoft/TypeScrpit#43213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43123) to track this issue.  For now I'd say that if you have a real use case that needs  to be constructed like your `G` and `H` above, and if you cannot wait for this issue to be fixed, then you work around it by using a type alias instead of the bare `never`, like this:

```
type N = never
type Gfixed = [N] extends [infer S1, ...infer S2] ? ([N] extends [S1] ? 1 : 2) : 3 // 1
```

---

Your question 3 is behaving as expected.  In type `K`, `(S1 extends never ? 1 : 2)` is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) because the type being checked, `S1`, is a type parameter.  And such a type function *distributes* over unions; meaning that if `F<T>` is distributive, then `F<X | Y>` will be equivalent to `F<X> | F<Y>`.

This implies that `F<never>` should be `never` (or at least that it would be a subtype of all possible answers for `F<T>`).  Why?  Because `X | never` is equivalent to `X`, so `F<X | never>` must be equivalent to `F<X> | F<never>`.  This means that for all `X`, `F<X> | F<never>` is equivalent to `F<X>`.  Conceptually, then, `F<never>` should be `never`.

And it turns out that the compiler does in fact treats `never` as ["the empty union"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23182#issuecomment-379094672) when used in a distributive conditional type.  This behavior definitely surprised me when I first ran into it, because it takes a certain shift in mindset to think of `never` as any kind of union.

Observe:

```
type Distributive<T> = T extends string ? { a: T } : { b: T };

type X = Distributive<"a"> // {a: "a"}
type Y = Distributive<0> // {b: 0}
type Z = Distributive<"a" | 0> // {a: "a"} | {b: 0}

type StillX = Distributive<"a" | never> // {a: "a"}
type Never = Distributive<never> // never
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAyghgWwgHgCpQgD2BAdgEwGcoBVAGlI2zyKgDUK6oBeKVAPhagDcB7AS3wBuAFBiRoSFABiXANq4I3CACcAulRwFic-rgBmq2AEYKAOgt7DK2ACYNAfigAKOTGMasW2gqWrHUMZQAFxQtgCUIVAAzBLg0ADi8orK6po0OlZG7uaWBtn2UE6uKf7p2lBuHkWBURFRsXFSAHJcpSpNifr8mBD48s2e1BW6+TY5UBZmWeOFxXKD5T7uAUGh9aHRUAD024FiktAAksl+aV4ZlTMmASVnQ946KzVrYZGbnVAAEqepD5ejawmXLTMZ2W6+P5LJ7VJyvDYxA7xb7dXr9VgLf4ja4TKY4uYuTHQyrPOF1d6Iz4AYQAFhAAMYAa2kSVY8CQyGkFASqL67FEhygtIZjK+JzZiBQX15+AoR354k+ABF+IRgCp+AAjACuwH4yjQnFY6AuFTVGtwAHMagBvKBwULoAC+UTtmsdUCdok+AA0uCrzVrdfqUAAiOChzi7KA2h1QcOhp2fACa-tV6qDeoNAAYo3sbe6oNmk4KAFppwM6rNhiNQAA+RbzMbjCZdDYLoWLSKkMD1ABs+37WAGM1WQ8gE-WoO0m7HQq3Ps0zhXR8GDTOdnt2iIgA)