# typescript intersection types of function

Tags: typescript

I am using typescript and faced some problems. The simplest demo would be:

```
type g = 1 & 2 // never
type h = ((x: 1) => 0) & ((x: 2) => 0) // why h not never
type i = ((x: 1 & 2) => 0)// why x not never
```

I don't understand why type `h` is not `never` and param `x` in type `i` is not `never`

```
type e = (((x: 1) => 0) & ((x: 2) => 0)) extends (x: infer L) => 0 ? L : never; //  why e is 2 not never or 1?
```

Also, didn't understand why type `e` is `2` not `never`?

Answer (score 8):

Note: non-primitive types are conventionally written in UpperCamelCase; this distinguishes them from primitive types and variable/property names.  I will use this convention in what follows.

There's a bunch of pieces to this question, and so there will be a bunch of pieces to its answer.

---

Let's tackle the easy ones first:

```
type G = 1 & 2 // never
```

The reduction to `never` of empty intersections like `1 & 2` was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#31838](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31838) and released with TypeScript 3.6.  Before this, `1 & 2` was treated very much like `never`, in that you'd never be able to find a value that satisfies it.  There's really no conceptual difference between `1 & 2` and `never`, although it's possible compiler implementation details will cause one to be treated differently from the other.

---

Next one:

```
type I = ((x: 1 & 2) => 0) // why x not never
```

The `x` *is* `never`, but the reduction is *deferred* until you actually use it:

```
type IParam = Parameters<I>[0]; // never
```

This deferral was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#36696](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/36696) and released with TypeScript 3.9.  Before this, `x` was eagerly reduced to `never` just like `G` above.

---

Now for some more complicated examples:

```
type H = ((x: 1) => 0) & ((x: 2) => 0) // why H not never
```

There are actually quite a few reasons why `H` is not `never`:

- The TypeScript-specific reason is because an intersection of function types is considered the same as an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) with multiple call signatures:

  ```
  declare const h: H;
  // 1/2 h(x: 1): 0
  // 2/2 h(x: 2): 0
  h(1); // okay
  h(2); // okay
  h(3); // error, no overload matches this call
  h(Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : 2); // error, no overload matches this call
  ```

  Notice how `h` is displayed as a function with two overloads; one which accepts a `1` parameter, and another which accepts a `2` parameter.  It does not accept `3`, and it also does not accept `1 | 2` even though from a pure type system perspective it probably should (see [microsoft/TypeScript#14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107) for a longstanding feature request to support this).
- Even if TypeScript didn't interpret function-intersections as overloads, `H` should not be `never`.  Function types are *contravariant* in their parameter types (see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covaraince-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc) for an explanation. You can also read about the contravariance of function parameters in [the TS handbook description of the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types)).  Contravariance turns things into their [dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(mathematics)); If `F<T>` is contravariant in `T`, then `F<T | U>` is equivalent to `F<T> & T<U>`, and `F<T & U>`  is equivalent to `F<T> | F<U>`.  So a consistent type system, when asked for the parameter type of an *intersection* of functions would return the *union* of the function parameter types.  And `1 | 2` is not `never`.
- Even if `H` *were* a completely uninhabited type, currently TypeScript only reduces intersections to `never` in particular situations, and an intersection of functions is not one of those.  If you look in the [compiler source code file `checker.ts`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/TypeScript/f0a72e24506ffe3165c595e12cd346c5314da3bb/src/compiler/checker.ts) it says "an intersection type is considered empty if it contains the type `never`, or more than one unit type or an object type and a nullable type (`null` or `undefined`), or a `string`-like type and a type known to be non-`string`-like, or a `number`-like type and a type known to be non-`number`-like, or a `symbol`-like type and a type known to be non-`symbol`-like, or a `void`-like type and a type known to be non-`void`-like, or a non-primitive type and a type known to be primitive."  None of that says "two incompatible function types", so it is not reduced to `never`.

---

Last one:

```
type E = (((x: 1) => 0) & ((x: 2) => 0)) extends (x: infer L) => 0 ? L : never;
//  why E is 2 not never or 1?
```

Recall from earlier that an intersection of functions is considered to be an overloaded function.  It is a known design limitation of TypeScript that when using type inference on an overloaded function type, the compiler does not try to resolve the overload by figuring out which call signature matches the intended inference best.  *It just uses the last call signature and ignores all the rest of them*.  In `E`, that means the compiler only sees `(x: 2) => 0` when matching against `(x: infer L) => 0`, and so `L` is inferred as `2`.  The "right" thing to do would probably be the union `1 | 2`, but this does not happen.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#27027](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27027) for one instance of this limitation.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBA4lC8UCMUBkUBMUD02oDsIA3CAJwChRIoBJBKACgYA8AuZNTASgQD4oADF1xQA7gAsQUZgQD2wAsTLlK4aDQAKAQ1JaAtvW269EYGQDOAHhq8A2gIC6Abhx5CJCquoAJekzbIPPD8Qpz+7BhBITwiElK++PKKHuQAJhAAxgA2OtAZsvjmCuLs3k7kIkjYWOIs7Ehc7AIVeBjVULUBkU3ktQ0uIrIA1logvQyRA3jDo+MAzFxTUGSksqQANHJQsh5ZslqpUHpawBniEOZQwOIAlpcZWllZ4wCyJ+IAdLr4qbJ6DDxLIIPgBWKAAfg4EUWrmWpFWGy2OzIewORxOZwuV1u90ezy80AAon5woE+IIeOhSZFyUIeBBmGYfpc6lAbvgAGZkKAAGSigghvKg7HcZHKIjEkigxLumDkClFpG2SqQ4KAA)

Comment: [With an implementation of `hoo: H`](https://tsplay.dev/WvppMN)

Comment: Great explanation! And are you free to answer another question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66469909/typescript-using-infer-with-never-get-different-result I have been stuck either.

Comment: I don't have time to go through all of those right now; I might look later

Answer (score 0):

in case

```
type h = ((x: 1) => 0) & ((x: 2) => 0)
```

you assign `1` as a type for `x` also known as literal type. Literal type is next to `never` smallest set of values. The difference between `never` and literal type `1` is that `never` is an empty set but `1` set which has exactly one value in it. So that `never` !== `1`

here

```
type i = (x: 1 & 2) => 0;
```

type of parameter `x` is `never`