# How to split intersection types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Have this kind of type:

```js
type A = 
  ((event: "click", value: []) => void) &
  ((event: "update", value: string) => void) &
  ((event: "delete", value: number) => void);
```

I want to split type A to this:

```js
type B = {
  click: (value: []) => void,
  update:(value: string) => void,
  delete: (value: number) => void,
}
```

Any idea to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not possible to do what you ask. [As jcalz detailed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66495246/1654241), intersection of functions are considered as function overloads, meaning that it is functionally equivalent to just the last member of the intersection.

If you were able to change your intersection type to a union type, then this would successfully build type `B`:

```js
type B = {
  [Handler in A as Parameters<Handler>[0]]:
    (value: Parameters<Handler>[1]) => ReturnType<Handler>
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8AoKKoAo0QG4QHbAC4oAiAYwBsBLUga2IBoosBDcgVwiIG0BdASgQA%20JgHtKAEwEAfZKgzY8hEmzDjmwCAyasORAM7AATpVwBzAfGFYxkqDNTpMOfEWLiI5CBq0t2nKLhsALYARhCGFlY2fADciIigkFAAQghQAN5QXAASzLjinoZQJrBQzHpQAArMhsxBXuF6ADy5%20YWCXAAMPDxEaL66VTV1DYbNrQXhHQCM-EJQAEpebIa4ACrgEC15k4bCAL6IAPRHqAB6APxAA)

Comment: Thank's, unfortunately it's a return type from Vue framework, i can't transform it to union type..
I'm also afraid that it's not possible, I hope someone has a solution.

Comment: I added a link to an answer by jcalz detailing what an intersection of functions is.