# In TypeScript, why does 'T extends never ? never : keyof T` differ from `keyof T'?

Tags: typescript, generics, conditional-types

Consider the following definitions:

```ts
type OtherKeyOf<T> = T extends never ? never : keyof T;
type OtherKeyOf2<T> = keyof T;
```

I would expect `OtherKeyOf` and `OtherKeyOf2` to act exactly the same, just as I would expect these two functions to act exactly the same:

```ts
const f1 = (t) => false ? false : "some_value";
const f2 = (t) => "some_value";
```

That isn't what happens, however. Given some dummy types `A` and `B`:

```ts
interface A {
 aMem: number;
}

interface B {
 bMem: string;
}
```

I get the following results:

```ts
let x: OtherKeyOf<A | B>;  // <= the type of x is `"aMem" | "bMem"`
let y: OtherKeyOf2<A | B>; // <= the type of y is `never`
```

I find this puzzling. Any help understanding this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Your `OtherKeyOf<T>` is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), which accounts for the difference in behavior.  See the answer to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64250340/why-this-customextract-returns-an-different-result-from-default-extract) for more info

Comment: Thank you @jcalz, that explains this nicely!