# Typescript exclude not working when replace same logic inline

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
type A = 'a' | 'b';
type B = 'b';
type C1 = Exclude<A, B>;  // C1 is 'a'
type C2 = A extends B ? never : A;  // C2 is 'a' | 'b'
```

Why is C1 and C2 different? I've just inline the logic inside `Exclude` in C2.

Comment: `Exclude` is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) because the type it checks is a bare type parameter (and not a specific type like `A`).  See the answer to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64250340/why-this-customextract-returns-an-different-result-from-default-extract) for more info.