# How to transform union type into union of arrays in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a `Foo` type which is a union of types

e.g.

```
type Foo = string | number
```

And I want to receive that type and transform it in an union of arrays of the types

```
type TransformedFoo = ToUnionOfArray<Foo> // => string[] | number[]
```

Usually, you can do something like `Foo[]` but it isn't what I want, because that would become `(string | number)[]`.

How can I have an union and transform it into a union of arrays of the types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use distributive conditionals in this case:

```js
type ToUnionOfArray<T> = T extends infer I ? I[] : never;
```

When T is a naked type parameter in a conditional statement the conditional applies (or distributes) over every value in the input union T.

More info on how that works here: [Typescript Distributive Conditional Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382306/typescript-distributive-conditional-types)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type Foo = string | number;

type Arrays<T> = T extends any ? T[] : never;

type TransformedFoo = Arrays<Foo>; // string[] | number[]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBnYAnAlgOwOZQA%20UOArgLYBGEGA3AFD2iRQCCGGAhiKgDwAqAPmRR%20UCAA9gEHABNUUTjhBQA-KIDaAXSgAuEhABuNBk3DR%20XHKgBmcDOQiz4iFOy49eLwbSgB6PzRMXDxtIhIKagxtIA)

> When conditional types act on a generic type, they become distributive when given a union type