# Why are these two definitions of FlatArray not equivalent?

Tags: typescript

I fail to understand why these two array-flattening types aren't equivalent :

```js
type FlatArray1<T> = Array<T extends Array<infer U> ? U : T>
type FlatArray2<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? Array<U> : Array<T>

type A = FlatArray1<boolean> // boolean[]
type B = FlatArray2<boolean> // false[] | true[]
```

**[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgQ2AQQE6oSAjAHgCoB8UAvFGhiPlBAB7AQB2AJgM5nqY4CWDAZhKigBVIgH5hUAFxRCAKFCRYiFBxAAmfEVJ5qdRq3YVufAcLGHOIqRcpz54aMhJKk5TLgBGAey9wICBiIAeiCob19-BgBtAF17RQAhZ3hXVQ1wvwDg0N4EOBYIWKgAHyhgVABXQpigA)**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382306/typescript-distributive-conditional-types) answer your question? In `FlatArray2`,  `T` is "naked". wrapping it will make it equivalent to `FlatArray1`: [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WvpzrN)

Comment: Ah yes, I see. I makes sense.

Comment: For some additional clarification, `boolean` is implemented under the hood as `type boolean = true | false`. Since it's a union, it's being distributed. Had your type not been a union, they would be equivalent.

Comment: Yes, I get it. You can post this as an answer.