# Difficulties to understand Typescript's distributive logic

Tags: typescript

So, I understand that [naked type parameter checks are distributive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55383816/11153160), thus :

```js
type B<T> = T extends true ? "X" : "Y";
type C = B<true | false>; // "X" | "Y"
```

But here is where I get lost :

1. `T` isn't naked in `A<T>`, but you still get distributivity :

```js
type A<T> = T;
type B<T> = A<T> extends true ? "X" : "Y";
type C = B<true | false>; // "X" | "Y" (??)
```

2. It gets weirder : distributivity goes away when infering `T` in `A` to itself :

```js
type A<T> = T extends infer U ? U : never;
type B<T> = A<T> extends true ? "X" : "Y";
type C = B<true | false>; // "Y" (??)
```

3. But it comes back when infering in `B` directly :

```js
type B<T> = T extends infer U ? (U extends true ? "X" : "Y") : never;
type C = B<true | false>; // "X" | "Y" (??)
```

Can you help me understand what's going on ? Thank you.

Comment: Only #1 seems weird to me.  #2 and #3 are how I'd expect things.  Not sure I can find an answer to what is going on with #1... or why anyone would write such a thing in the first place.  Someone (me? you?) might try filing #1 as a bug and seeing what they say, but it's unlikely to be me doing it tonight.

Comment: @jcalz One reason to write #1 might be to avoid distributivity, as in `[T] extends [true] ?`. I will do the bug report.

Comment: @jcalz https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43727

Comment: @jcalz why is `T` in #1 considered not naked? If it's a type parameter that appears alone and is not part of some more complex type expression, doesn't it make it naked? Or is `T` alone not considered a type expression?

Comment: In `A<T> extends true`, the `T` does not seem to be naked, it is apparently "clothed" by `A<...>`. Presumably `T` gets substituted for `A<T>` in the definition of `B<T>` before the conditional type is evaluated for distributivity, but this is surprising to me.

Comment: Hey, looks like #43727 is "working as intended" but I'm not sure I understand the stated reasoning.  As I mentioned in that issue, I'm inclined to think of it as an order-of-operations thing.  But who knows.  Anyway if you still want an answer here I can write one up

Comment: I don't need it personally, but if you think that might be of interest for other people, go ahead.