# Union Types Inside Union Types

Tags: typescript

I'm confused as why this is a type error:

```
type A = A1 | A2;

type A1 = {
  attr: B1;
}

type A2 = {
  attr: B2
};

type B = B1 | B2;

type B1 = {
  attr: "B1"
};

type B2 = {
  attr: "B2"
};


function b(): B {
  return {
    attr: "B1"
  };
}

function a(): A {
  return {
    attr: b()
  }
}
```

This yields the following error:

```
Type '{ attr: B; }' is not assignable to type 'A'.
  Type '{ attr: B; }' is not assignable to type 'A2'.
    Types of property 'attr' are incompatible.
      Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'B2'.
        Type 'B1' is not assignable to type 'B2'.
          Types of property 'attr' are incompatible.
            Type '"B1"' is not assignable to type '"B2"'.ts(2322)
```

As `b` returns either `B1` or `B2` it should adhere to `A`'s `attr` type.

So I don't really understand what's happening here, as it seems to me that there's no type violation.

EDIT:

I found a "solution" but it is rather verbose, so I'm still looking for a cleaner way to make the compiler happy.

```
function isB1(b: B): b is B1 {
  return b.attr === "B1";
}

function isB2(b: B): b is B2 {
  return b.attr === "B2";
}

function b(): B {
  return {
    attr: "B1",
  };
}

function a(): A {
  const B = b();
  if(isB1(B)) {
    return {
      attr: B,
    };
  }

  return {
    attr: B
  };
}
```

Comment: The answer seems to be that typescript just doesn't recognize `{x: A} | {x: B}` and `{x: A | B}` as the same. I'll look to see if I can find a more authoritative answer or a github issue, but this is the best I can find for now. FWIW, `A[keyof A]` forces this collapse.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382306/typescript-distributive-conditional-types) might help.

Comment: The relevant github issues are [ms/TS#8289](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8289) and [ms/TS#12052](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12052), btw

Comment: Also [ms/TS#18758](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758) shows that there are no "nested discriminated unions", so the compiler cannot use [the smarter union type checking introduced in TS3.5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#smarter-union-type-checking) to see that object literals of type `{attr: B}` are assignable to type `A`.