# Is `distributive conditional types` the desired behavior typically? Why?

Tags: typescript

`https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types`

> Typically, distributivity is the desired behavior. To avoid that behavior, you can surround each side of the extends keyword with square brackets.

Is `distributive conditional types` the desired behavior typically? What are the use cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because distributivity over [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) is often the most natural behavior for type operations.

Let's say you have a function like

```
declare function f<T>(x: T): F<T>;
```

which takes a value of type `T` and returns a value of type `F<T>` where `F` is some generic type function.  If you have a value `a` of some type `A`, and a value `b` of some type `B`, then `f(a)` will be of type `F<A>` and `f(b)` will be of type `F<B>`:

```
declare function f<T>(x: T): F<T>;
const fa = f(a); // F<A>
const fb = f(b); // F<B>
```

Now, what happens when you pass *either* `a` *or* `b` to `f()` and assign the result to a variable?

```
const fab = f(Math.random() < 0.5 ? a : b); // F<A | B>
```

The input is of type `A | B`, so the output must be `F<A | B>` by definition.  On the other hand, what happens if you *either* call `f(a)` *or* `f(b)` and assign the result to a variable?

```
const fafb = Math.random() < 0.5 ? f(a) : f(b); // F<A> | F<B>
```

Well, the result must be `F<A> | F<B>` by definition.

But compare `fab` to `fafb`; for any reasonable implementation of `f()`, you would predict the exact same set of possible values for `fab` and `fafb`, right?  `fab` is the result of `f(a)` or `f(b)` since the input is either `a` or `b`, and `fafb` is also the result of `f(a)` or `f(b)`.  That implies that the type `F<A | B>` and the type `F<A> | F<B>` **should be the same type**.

This is exactly what it means to distribute a type function over a union.  A type function `F<>` distributes over unions if and only if `F<T | U>` is equivalent to `F<T> | F<U>` for all types `T` and `U`.

---

So then, any use case where you represent a data transformation with a type operation will probably be one where you would like that type operation to be distributive over unions.  Let's examine some common distributive type operations in TypeScript.

[Indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) are distributive over unions:

```
interface I { x: string, y: number };
type IX = I["x"]; // string
type IY = I["y"]; // number
type IXY = I["x" | "y"]; // string | number
type IXIY = I["x"] | I["y"]; // string | number

type Also = ({ a: string } | { a: number })["a"] // string | number
```

When [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) are [homomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism) (where you are mapping with `in keyof` as introduced in [ms/TS#12447](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12447) when it was called *isomorphic*, see [this question/answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59791889/2887218)), they are distributive over unions:

```
type HomMap<T> = { [K in keyof T]: (x: T[K]) => void };
type MA = HomMap<{ a: string }>; // type MA = {  a: (x: string) => void; }
type MB = HomMap<{ b: string }>; // type MB = {  b: (x: string) => void; }
type MAB = HomMap<{ a: string } | { b: string }> 
  // type MAB = HomMap<{ a: string; }> | HomMap<{ b: string; }> 
type MAMB = HomMap<{ a: string; }> | HomMap<{ b: string; }> 
  // type MAMB = HomMap<{ a: string; }> | HomMap<{ b: string; }>
```

And, of course, [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) where the checked type is a generic type parameter are distributive:

```
type DCT<T> = T extends { a: string } ? number : string;
type DA = DCT<{ a: string }> // number
type DB = DCT<{ b: string }> // string
type DAB = DCT<{ a: string } | { b: string }>
// type DAB = string | number
type DADB = DCT<{ a: string }> | DCT<{ b: string }>
// type DADB = string | number
```

---

At this point you might wonder which type operations should *not* distribute over unions.  This concept is strongly tied with **variance** (see [this q/a for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66411491/2887218)).  Type functions that are *covariant*, such as those representing property reads or data outputs, should be distributive over unions.  Type functions that are *contravariant*, such as those representing property writes or data inputs, should also distribute after a fashion, but turn unions into [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types).  But quite often you will get *invariant* type functions, such as those representing arbitrary operations, and in these cases you don't want to distribute over unions.  So it is sometimes useful to be able to turn off distributivity.  I won't belabor the point showing examples here, though.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPAFQHxQLxQVCAPYEB2AJgM5QDeUAhgFxTHABOAlvgOZQC+UA-FPgK4BbAEYQGUWvWZsA3ACgWeBgDNKAY2gBBclUmMW7DvMVjVGqACEdwvdMPzCENQBtKDaGoD2+erqiaHJ1d3KC8fYCgbS3k5Rxc3aGV+fDVgJm8oZUQkAApsWgQASlp4ZHkw31U0TJzKQpkoAHpG2DhNJDkKiOVhauUc4XqmlvgLDs7vSspe9H6AWUpgAAsAOgZKIk9BHMKoOCgABhWAVh4qCUih5tbtAB9LDq7Myh7qheW1jcItnb3Dk7O-TqF36gwa13g7Sg91G4wU+CUZmgAEkdPk6Po2AAaKAgWgCERiTjyUCQKDIgAa1WRAG0AETYOkAXXBLSkBjkpJRAE1qfSQMzWXwhKIGJzwCiKbz0LSGXToVA6QKWcMMXYFQTReKyZTkdLyfTGUyFbLlUL2WwNSKxHJtVpnMRPNUchQaGqDJwFa78dbxBxCvTKMzVRb2PdNTa7VAABJbBZgbLVCg0gDSUBYUAA1hAQJ5lBgmbQ8gVU0zdqgUAA3TxMQjEqNzbToWOCeNwb3uy0cJBCrlQRtJqB+Yud1jlqs1wgNDgNqzNuOUBMUKKhzg91V9uZznSRIvo0PjqDV2vThuabcttsd1dce7L2we7tya6b8-VS+L9t+UPTlD3D9Lruo6-lAZ5bu+C6AW6P5rgqAFfiumKsL+z4tK+4Hzq2n7XkhIH-pBCEPrIa62n2AAiADCCCJugmA4HgRCkDh6pcLwEbiERyFRmRTZQJR1HMY+KDXOx3HbvxhGjrB1yhtxb7oBJgldl6QE3h0L4Snx8lSeGvpyWR4lUV+0FIbB9yKapplPhpZI8QZ1SrrphJinIQA)

Comment: Thank for your patient answer. So distributive type occurs in every generic type accepted union types, not only in conditional generic types?

Comment: Yes, distributivity over unions happens in multiple type operations, as shown.  But not every type function is distributive... for example, you can get non-distributive mapped types if you prevent them from being homomorphic, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7KOPN).

Comment: Why `[T] extends [U]?` could turn off distributivity? That's hardcode syntax?

Comment: See the documentation for [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types); the rule used to turn on distributive conditional types is that the checked type is a generic type parameter by itself... so `T extends ...` is distributive if `T` is a generic type parameter.  But `[T] extends ...` or `{a: T} extends ...` or `AnythingElse<T> extends ...` is not distributive because those are not generic type parameters.   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382306/typescript-distributive-conditional-types

Comment: @jcalz where can I find more info about the relation between variance and distribution (covariance -> unions, contravariance -> intersection)?

Comment: Hmm, not sure if I know of a particular reference.  If you have a covariant type function `F<T>` then you can prove that `F<A> | F<B>` must be assignable to `F<A | B>` and that `F<A & B>` must be assignable to `F<A> & F<B>` but you need extra assumptions to prove that they are equal.  Similarly for a contravariant type function `G<T>` you can prove `G<A> | G<B>` is assignable to `G<A & B>` and that `G<A | B>` is assignable to `G<A> & G<B>` but again, you need extra assumptions to prove equality.

Comment: @jcalz https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48240#issuecomment-1066489189 proposed some unifications: co`F` => `F<A> | F<B>` unified as `F<A | B>`, contra`G` => `G<A> | G<B>` unified as `G<A & B>`, but it seems like they could generate unsoundess, so I'd interested about those extra assumptions you mentioned. My problem is that I have no idea where to find material about what you are saying, because I'd like to understand better.