# Why type F<T extends { type: any }, U> = T["type"] extends U ? true : false always false

Tags: typescript, types

```
type F<T extends { type: any }, U> = T["type"] extends U ? true : false;
let f: F<{ type: string } | { type: number }, number>;
```

The type of f is false,
why the type is not boolean?

Comment: Your code currently throws a compile error - you never defined `type`. Did you mean `['type']`?

Comment: yes，it's T["type"]

Comment: Because `string | number` does not extend `number`, and your conditional type is not [distributive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), so it's not splitting up `string | number` into its union constituents.

Comment: See the answer to the linked question for why `T["type"] extends U ? true : false` is not distributive

Comment: You are right。more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382306/typescript-distributive-conditional-types