# How can I make TypeScript infer a return type more "literally"?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I've been scratching my head and searching the internet for an explanation to this.

I started with my full code and boiled it down to the following that illustrates my problem:

```
function foo (param: string) {
    if (param === 'bar') {
        return {
            one: 'bar'
        }
    }

    return {
        two: 'baz'
    }
}
```

Why does this give me:

```
declare function foo(param: string): {
    one: string;
    two?: undefined;
} | {
    two: string;
    one?: undefined;
};
```

and not

```
declare function foo(param: string): {
    one: string;
} | {
    two: string;
};
```

At first I thought it was a difference between functions and arrow functions, but [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45247) taught me otherwise and pointed me in the direction that it might be an inference issue.

Then I came across [Distributive Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)
 and thought it might have something to do with it but having read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55383816/9735558) (and hopefully understood it correctly) made me think that it was not.

I have now read a lot of other resources too, but I can't figure out what I'm missing or why I can't put all the pieces together to form an understanding of this.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1&jsx=1&ts=4.8.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZyogFABwIYBOeAtgFyIYExgDmAlIgN4BQibiMw2+RxiAvIMQByYHDjCGLdjMQEUUEASTTZahCnKjxw1msQBfPWyPG5CpSrMyoAdzhaARoV0yjBoA)

Comment: I think this is how TypeScript was designed. If it returned a union without optional properties, it would be a lot more annoying to work with these kinds of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem here; the type inferred by Typescript here is more useful than the one you propose.

An object type like `{one: string}` does not mean that an object of that type can only have that one property. This type only means the object must have that property, with no restriction on what other properties the object has. In contrast, a type like `{one: string, two?: undefined}` means that the object has the property `one` and *does not* have the property `two`, except possibly with the value `undefined`.

This means that the inferred type is more specific: the object either has `one` and not `two`, or it has `two` and not `one`. That's more informative than just saying the object either has `one` or `two`, because that also means it could have both.

---

Also note here that when you access an object's properties, Typescript will give you an error if the property is not declared on that type. For example, accessing the property `obj.two` when `obj` has type `{one: string} | {two: string}` will give a type error, and it should: an object of this type could look like `{one: 'fish', two: 3.14}`, i.e. its `two` property could be literally anything.

On the other hand, `{one: string, two?: undefined} | {one?: undefined, two: string}` has the property `two` in both branches, so there is no type error when you access `obj.two`. This is because Typescript can know the type of `obj.two` - it's definitely either `string` or `undefined`, it cannot be anything else.

```
type Foo = {one: string, two?: undefined} | {two: string, one?: undefined}

// error, as desired
let foo: Foo = {one: 'fish', two: 'fish'};

// ok
foo.one;


type Bar = {one: string} | {two: string}

// object is wrong, but no error :-(
let bar: Bar = {one: 'fish', two: 'fish'};

// error when trying to use the object in a sensible way :-(
bar.one;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1&jsx=1&ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLU4DsIBcUAzsAE4CWuA5gNybbADucA-EQK64AmEAZlQjd6AXygAfNAyzM4RUpRr1sOfOyhdeA-MPQj06UJCgAhAIZlkUlXkIlyVOnonXGLeQ6V6DAeh9QIMjI4MgAaKDNiKF5iCjIhdAAbCGAoPgQieEQUVFsiAHIBYgALfPDZAqLSkXp0PxwAIwArCABjVIoopmCacIaOVNxEQODLAgBaAAoklKgGiyJzSxy8qELO0vL3Nar8moN0uAA6W1ooergAa3R5shP8M-qRkKgmYohcKHIQRy-EDmI0GA70aLXaUCoERIH1iDWSrzMICgE2mQA)

Comment: The last paragraph is what made it click for me, finally! The wording of the last sentence is key! Makes so much sense now. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since `key?: undefined` can still be declared, you can do guard checking on the property:

```
function test(bool: boolean) {
    if (bool)
        return { one: "bar" }
    else
        return { two: "baz" }
}

if (test(true).one) {
    // this wouldn't work otherwise
}

function test2(bool: boolean): { one: string } | { two: string } {
    if (bool)
        return { one: "bar" }
    else
        return { two: "baz" }
}

if (test2(true).one) {
    // as shown!
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1&jsx=1&ts=4.8.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgEZzgGwC5FcCUBDMASkQG8AoRJxGYRHPfKx53gJxRQQfJLUQIUxAETZyfKYgC%20PJinxoUK3ogFCRdZAHc402QC8Fy5fVbtUGTFD4gUVAHQSaDXgHofyAAsYNERjEHwAEzAAcihQuD4Aa3EoAJQ%20Q2DNa1BIWARkdCgAJg4CYlJ8CmpiMQliDD4YMABzJUQAHwMoYwanZrbFOi1bMq4tfkFhUXEwSUQZOUstNQ0J5l1p7t6F82XrUfsSx2dXDzmvLT9EchC0ALhDMABCekUgA)