# In TypeScript, how can you confirm that an array contains all the possible values of a string literal union type?

Tags: arrays, typescript, string-literals

I have a string literal union type inherited from a library, and it has hundreds of members (the `IconName` type from [@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/js-packages/%40fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types/index.d.ts), if you're curious). I am not able to redefine this type or use an enum instead.

I know that you can't convert a string literal union to an Array. But is there some way to use types to ensure that an array contains *all* the possible values of a string literal union?

I can do something like

```
const iconNames: IconName[] = [
  ...
]
```

but that only guarantees that all members of the array are valid `IconName`, it doesn't guarantee that the list is exhaustive.

Is there a way to exhaustively confirm that all members of an array conform to a type, and that the array lists all possible values of the type?

As I said, I don't control this type so I can't just rewrite it as an enum, or rewrite it as an array then derive the union type from the array.  The intended use case here is to give users a dropdown to choose an icon from the list of possible valid values.

Comment: Your solution might be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60132060