# How to enforce Typescript to check that all keys in an object are present in array, where said keys are used as a value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is there any easy to way ensure all keys of an object, are present on another object property?

For example:

```js
export interface Field<T> {
  formKey: Extract<keyof T, string>;
  label: string;
  text: string;
}

export interface FormProps<T> {
  initState: T;
  fields: Field<T>[];
  title: string;
}


const initState = {
 name: 'whatever',
 description: 'whocares'
}
```

Is it possible for Typescript to check that for `fields`, all keys present in `initState`, exist in that array of objects, where those keys get assigned to `formKey`?

So if you passed:

```js
const mockExposureProps: FormProps<FormInfo.Exposure> = {
  fields: [
    {
      formKey: "description",
      label: "mock-label",
      text: "mock-text",
    },
  ],
  initState: {
    description: "mock-desc",
    name: "mock-name",
  },
  title: "cool title",
};
```

Typescript would let you know, you didn't also pass an object that has a `formKey` of `name`

EDIT:

The closest I can get is this:

```js
export interface Field<T> {
  formKey: Pick<T, keyof T>; // Change occurred here
  label: string;
  text: string;
}
```

But then my data structure needs to change to:

```js
const mockExposureProps: FormProps<FormInfo.Exposure> = {
  fields: [
    {
      formKey: { // Change occurred here
        description: 'mock-desc',
      }
    },
      label: "mock-label",
      text: "mock-text",
    },
  ],
  initState: {
    description: "mock-desc",
    name: "mock-name",
  },
  title: "cool title",
};
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do that within a type. You could possibly do it with the help of a helper function by a doing a variation of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60131681/make-sure-array-has-all-types-from-a-union

Comment: However given you're using it within react I don't think that will work. The closest I can come up with is if you change fields from an array to an object. Then you can enforce all the keys map to the `initState`. If that works I can type up an answer for you.

Comment: @zecuria Yeah that works, give it a shot, please! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is possible to enforce it in a very round about way by doing using a helper function as shown: [Make sure array has all types from a union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60131681/make-sure-array-has-all-types-from-a-union)

I don't think that would really work in the context of react and using it within a component. Instead what I would recommend is changing the type definition to:

```js
export interface Field {
  label: string;
  text: string;
}

export interface FormProps<T> {
  initState: T;
  fields: Record<keyof T, Field>;
  title: string;
}
```

This way you can easily enforce that each of the keys present in initState must also be present in field.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgMQWABsATOAbwCg45jMAjEgLjgGcYpkBzAbhrioQMVhy5I+VAL5UqoSLEQo0WXAWgBbAApQIYNgB4AKgD5KA5AhgBlGJlSsj-WuiJk2rAErBs0UgYBrYABPCHQ4IwAaAjdSE2dBK2JgUU4efhkqGGCwPCNgDjgAXko4JEwNFPY0iV44UgLsLjAYBAgkVPFuTN8kQo0IbACAUXAINgBXKGAdPQ91KG1dfWMCmDMS6hdY+a3aesbm1vbWPf26RhY4ACIBoYBaeiZia8iBc6ERG7uA+8-X95wKRvc7lSqnQG0J5XW6DX7Ql4g86CUBfWEPf5I2jAgQ42iWGx2Bzmc4NNhNBAtNodb5w+5k7AA0EVKro35g4BMoFI1owZKsa6+CDERJ8zlvKS8IA)

Comment: Alright yeah, this is a good idea. This is more straightforward than doing a bunch of helper functions. I'll give this route a shot. Thanks and accepted.