# How to constraint an array with keyof of a type?

Tags: typescript

Sorry if the question sounds vague, basically;

I have a struct

```
type User = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
}
```

I specifically want to map the attributes into an array by doing

```
type UserKey = Array<keyof User>;
```

Later in the code, I want to map the variables which has UserKey type into something else, say into table headers

```
let tableHeaders: UserKey = ["name", "age"];
```

Everything is working as expected, but I want the array to have every key from the User so nothing is left out if the case maybe I add another attribute to User type in the future, the code will show error because not all key is covered in the array

```
let tableHeaders: UserKey = ["name", "age", "gender"]; // this will error as expected
let tableHeaders: UserKey = ["name"]; // this will not error, but I want this to error instead
```

Expectation:

```
let tableHeaders: UserKey = ["name"]; // ERROR, age key is required
```

Comment: See also: [Make sure array has all types from a union](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60131681/12299000)

Comment: TypeScript doesn't have the concept of an "exhaustive" array, there are only workarounds, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDkrVw).  See answers to linked questions.