# Union of enum values as type

Tags: typescript, enums, union-types

I'm trying to use type safety for a specific scenario. Imagine we have:

```
const enum Color {
  red = 'red',
  blue = 'blue',
}

const enum Shape {
  rectangle = 'rectangle',
  square = 'square',
  circle = 'circle'
}
```

Is it possible to create a type that would accept either the values of the first enum or the second?

What I've tried:

```
type Characteristics =
  | `${Color}`
  | `${Shape}`

const characteristic: Characteristics[] = ['circle', 'red']; // should fail, but it does not
```

But I couldn't fully satisfy my requirements as that array can take any of the enum values.

What I need is:

```
const char1: Characteristics[] = ['circle', 'square']; // good
const char2: Characteristics[] = ['circle', 'red']; // fail
const char3: Characteristics[] = []; // fail
const char4: Characteristics[] = ['test', 'red', 'blue']; // fail
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `(keyof typeof Color)[] | (keyof typeof Shape)[]` to declare an array type with items either only of type `Color` or only of type `Shape`.

To ensure that the array has at least one value declare a [Tuple Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgYRAGxAJxgbwCgYYc4ATGAXhgCIzzaAaYmAI00Tmro6+cIBfQoVCRYCFDADKACwCGAB25ESZYFHlgA5pm416cDVt1wBJCAEdE8sj1pWbZczGABLHMD333nvQOFCKABPZXQsXAgeAGs4YJAAMxgQ5UTw7BwAbiDQ7jklOCiaWPiklLg0-OVsnLC0BRx5DTgcN2g3YCKYAG0MDIgmGAA6Eb7I7oBdCZgAHx6qwsGRoYWISYmavVhgBoAudAamqBa2qA6IGp3bHm7aXy8zQYdrWzMNmAB6D5htEBByUQNG6GRhPPhvTKfb6-f6A640W73fxPBi0d5fGAJeRuTBwvAIu4eB7MOio9HfLE4vE3cmY7G4q74nq0Y7QEkg9ngtGQjGU3FAA) with a fixed first item and a spreaded array on the second index.

```
const enum Color {
  red = "red",
  blue = "blue",
}

const enum Shape {
  rectangle = "rectangle",
  square = "square",
  circle = "circle",
}

type Colors = keyof typeof Color;
type Shapes = keyof typeof Shape;

type Characteristics = [Colors, ...Colors[]] | [Shapes, ...Shapes[]];

let char: Characteristics;

char = ["circle", "square"]; // good
char = ["red", "blue"]; // good
char = ["circle", "red"]; // fail
char = ["circle", "red"]; // fail
char = []; // fail
char = ["test", "red", "blue"]; // fail
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgYRAGxAJxgbwCgYYc4ATGAXhgCIzzaAaYmAI00Tmro6+cIBfQoVCRYCFDADKACwCGAB25ESZYFHlgA5pm416cDVt1wBJCAEdE8sj1pWbZczGABLHMD333nvQOFCKABPZXQsXAgeAGs4YJAAMxgQ5UTw7BwAbiDQ7jklOCiaWPiklLg0-OVsnLC0BRx5DTgcN2g3YCKYAG0MDIgmGAA6Eb7I7oBdCZgAHx6qwsGRoYWISYmavVhgBoAudAamqBa2qA6IGp3bHm7aXy8zQYdrWzMNmAB6D5htEBByUQNG6GRhPPhvTKfb6-f6A640W73fxPBi0d5fGAJeRuTBwvAIu4eB7MOio9HfLE4vE3cmY7G4q74nq0Y7QEkg9ngtGQjGU3FAA)

Comment: That does it! Thank you. Follow up question though, if I were the add the requirement that all of the keys need to be present of each of the enums, how would that look like? 

So the char array has to contain ('rectangle' AND 'square' AND 'circle') OR ('red' AND 'blue').

I tried working with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60131681/make-sure-array-has-all-types-from-a-union/60132060#60132060 but having the union of the unions overcomplicates things

Answer (score 0):

See this answer for some reference: [Is it possible to define a non empty array type in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56006111/is-it-possible-to-define-a-non-empty-array-type-in-typescript)

With that in mind, the following would do.

```
type NonEmptyArray<T> = [T, ...T[]];
type Characteristics = NonEmptyArray<Color>|NonEmptyArray<Shape>;
```