# Is there a way to define type for array with unique items in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-types

The type should detect if the array has duplicate items and throw error in typescript?

```
type UniqueArray = [
  // How to implement this?
]

const a:UniqueArray = [1, 2, 3] // success
const b:UniqueArray = [1, 2, 2] // error
```

PS: I'am currently removing duplicate items using JS, but, curious if this error can be captured using typescript type before hand?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes! There is a way with TypeScript 4.1 (in beta at the time of writing). This is how:

```js
const data = ["11", "test", "tes", "1", "testing"] as const
const uniqueData: UniqueArray<typeof data> = data

type UniqueArray<T> =
  T extends readonly [infer X, ...infer Rest]
    ? InArray<Rest, X> extends true
      ? ['Encountered value with duplicates:', X]
      : readonly [X, ...UniqueArray<Rest>]
    : T

type InArray<T, X> =
  T extends readonly [X, ...infer _Rest]
    ? true
    : T extends readonly [X]
      ? true
      : T extends readonly [infer _, ...infer Rest]
        ? InArray<Rest, X>
        : false
```

You'll get a compiler error if the same value occurs more than once.

[Here's my article describing things in better detail.](https://ja.nsommer.dk/articles/type-checked-unique-arrays.html)

[Try in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtARARh1gGhiygFNpDiyJLdbqoBLMAcywF0YEIZRIoAUH2gwArmEYBHUaQAiSBAC4YAVQnTSAQQBO2hAE8APFH0AHUiABm8BQD40N5AIEnzq9TJ16jAFXuoBGBgfGFIADzIwOB5tUgQ4cAAbfUxmS1JtGAANIgA6fLSMmAAlcih2QKCYAH4YAEkwLwNDUugiLPtwyOiYKG0ZSqqazAByAFEwUHEyWLgYADcERJkYAHdGKAALeFFTRMZgJHJFEfaKoaDlWPiklIwcmHzctSlPXWbWqFtzquUfZ1cpHqjXevna-kqIS6pCiMTiCTAyUwDyehUyAH1Pj8grU%20gMhn9QhEYT1rgikfdsVVcf1SINfsEid04TdEXc0TB0XkCmB0pksfShrUGk0jJ9wYKGZYlhA6UA)

Comment: I imagine this only works for relatively short tuples due to the shallow recursion limits; or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz, when a TypeScript contributor says there's shallow recursion limits, I'm inclined to believe that's indeed a limitation of my answer.

Comment: Although smart, you have to wonder if it isn't more readable to use a `new Set()` if you want each value to occur only once?

Comment: @Kokodoko That's evaluated at runtime. This is compile time.

Comment: Yes, but a `Set()` also has a type: `let uniqueItems : Set<string> = new Set<string>()`.

Comment: Also a `Set` implies that the data is un-ordered. `new Set(["foo", "bar"])` is the same as `new Set(["bar", "foo"])` while two `UniqueArray`s of the same data are not.

Comment: having to type out  const data = ["11", "test", "tes", "1", "testing"] as const
kind of defeats the purpose. we come back to the issue of having to set a type of string literals in a tupe array in order to use ur example

Answer (score 32):

The only possible way this could work at compile time is if your arrays are [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) composed of [literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types).  For example, here are some arrays with the same runtime values, but with different types in TypeScript:

```
const tupleOfLiterals: [1, 2, 2] = [1, 2, 2]; 
const tupleOfNonLiterals: [number, number, number] = [1, 2, 2];
const arrayOfLiterals: (1 | 2)[] = [1, 2, 2];
const arrayOfNonLiterals: number[] = [1, 2, 2];

const constAssertedReadOnlyTupleOfLiterals = [1, 2, 2] as const;
```

Only the first one would behave as you'd like... the compiler would realize that `tupleOfLiterals` has exactly 3 elements, two of which are the same type.  In all the other cases, the compiler doesn't understand what's going on.  So if you're passing arrays you get from other functions, or from an API, etc., and the type of these arrays is something like `number[]`, then the answer is just "no, you can't do this".

---

If you're getting tuples of literals (possibly via [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions))... say, from a developer using your code as a library, then you have a chance of getting something that works, but it's complex and possibly brittle.  Here's how I might do it:

First we come up something that acts like an [invalid type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689), which TypeScript doesn't have.  The idea is a type to which no value can be assigned (like [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never)) but which produces a custom error message when the compiler encounters it.  The following isn't perfect, but it produces error messages that are possibly reasonable if you squint:

```
type Invalid<T> = Error & { __errorMessage: T };
```

Now we represent `UniqueArray`. It can't be done as a concrete type (so no `const a: UniqueArray = ...`) but we *can* represent it as a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) that we pass to a helper function.  Anyway, here's `AsUniqueArray<A>` which takes a candidate array type `A` and returns `A` if it is unique, and otherwise returns a different array where there are error messages in the places that are repeated:

```
type AsUniqueArray<
  A extends ReadonlyArray<any>,
  B extends ReadonlyArray<any>
> = {
  [I in keyof A]: unknown extends {
    [J in keyof B]: J extends I ? never : B[J] extends A[I] ? unknown : never
  }[number]
    ? Invalid<[A[I], "is repeated"]>
    : A[I]
};
```

That uses a lot of [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [conditional](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) types, but it essentially walks through the array and looks to see if any other elements of the array match the current one.  If so, there's an error message.

Now for the helper function.  Another wrinkle is that by default, a function like `doSomething([1,2,3])` will treat `[1,2,3]` as a `number[]` and not a `[1,2,3]` tuple of literals.  There's no [simple way to deal with this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680), so we have to use weird magic (see the link for discussion of that magic):

```
type Narrowable =
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | object
  | null
  | undefined
  | symbol;

const asUniqueArray = <
  N extends Narrowable,
  A extends [] | ReadonlyArray<N> & AsUniqueArray<A, A>
>(
  a: A
) => a;
```

Now, `asUniqueArray()` just returns its input at runtime, but at compile time it will only accept array types it perceives as unique, and it will put errors on the problem elements if there are repeats:

```
const okay = asUniqueArray([1, 2, 3]); // okay

const notOkay = asUniqueArray([1, 2, 2]); // error!
//                                ~  ~
// number is not assignable to Invalid<[2, "is repeated"]> | undefined
```

Hooray, that is what you wanted, right?  The caveats from the beginning still hold, so if you end up getting arrays that are already widened (either non-tuples or non-literals), you'll have undesirable behavior:

```
const generalArray: number[] = [1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2];
const doesntCareAboutGeneralArrays = asUniqueArray(generalArray); // no error

const arrayOfWideTypes: [number, number] = [1, 2];
const cannotSeeThatNumbersAreDifferent = asUniqueArray(arrayOfWideTypes); // error,
// Invalid<[number, "is repeated"]>
```

Anyway, all this might not be worth it for you, but I wanted to show that there is kind of, sort of, maybe, a way to get close to this with the type system.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCuAHANgUwPIDMAyBLKqATgIbIQBcMA2gIwA0MATA4wLowC819TLrA3AFgAUKEiwEKDJgBy4PARJlKVMPAC2AIyIM1WnTD3bC7LrRZ8ho8NBjFCJAJ5YFRUhRgAKGjAA+TAEoqU24LJgERMVt7Jyw5MFclDyMiYM5Q3nCrSJtYKKgAQQgIIgIAEwAlVGIy9DBkRwAVJDQXfDcydPNMtjsIGHzs4ShHRFQYAEkwADdSXDKAHkaAPnSAUQcQQhgAMhgAbxgAfSOiQi2AWVRi4gBzVEpGmABfIZGxmCKAVTBcAEd4KgCg5iI4FiIYJ8YKgAB4EMBlfpVGrgBrApwLYhgRzLOgQmAAIWhcNQCKR1TKqMc6NBmOxy3xqy4+3xkKoExguDAMAA1qhHCBMJ9WJR4GAeWAQAB3bmw+GIg6syHUABSnO5fIFQoJIpgarlpIVHIA-IZUNMiDBKASqCr2AayZ92exTWKJdLuZQwOaiErnqoNMZWErTVNZsh5gsqAVnQwAES4fqEVBjYjlOOsBnCZVWp0TYPZl5vUbjGQxaXETRoTj4-zQQhc261wyB32F-yaEAgNBY5sgTQAK1QwCgzbUyGQzbFZVQmC5qDKzYgji03aG+T6P3+gJpjnS4MLMmJ8v6Zc2UsraDxhYKx8N-TS-mRlPq1JBYJkqz231+AKB74WAoGAKLNlk8fFiEoAoRACThVmIddchgEAeVBdJiAgLc-13TxumYGAAGZWACfgYAAejI5DUMcHJxEMEAoHQaj0Mw38d3fXCeHwtgSPIyizi2ABCEQKJzMTxIkyTIQAPxkkTKJSbZE3o2AMIgXBbjAS9xigEBJhmOZFiofCEyTFNqnTTM-BgadZ3nRdhHkmAAGECgANTWApGgAZVo2x7m9JRdy9VtCDSMwuLCSKYC4iJrDoylrjAKBnPsIFO3gKAAHFSQ6Xd+i4DCsPYpxPACvL3140TJWhTZCBEPzVPfLAAHV5lQRoSw8AN9EIXRQpCPC4o3YAsUlKBvNQDqAAs0xkUKIGBVAABFcEwTAiFJWBCtY7d-1KmJQVa9rOrGCAqv4urr1EsNDKjRT42U5NU0srNGoGXIihKQhyi6WK+g+8QrA3KUth5ArNzY-bQU8fIvtKBcLqo0EGsctHUaAA)

Comment: Thanks. This is crazy. I have a use case where I have a type array of predefined strings. I prefer user to pass array with unique strings in that case. I'll see if this works for me 

Comment: Is there a way to use this approach as a type? Something like `type MyType = 'foo' | 'bar'` and `AsUniqueArray<MyType[]>`?

Comment: What are you expecting that to evaluate to?  The union of all possible tuples with those values in them?

Answer (score 6):

Is very similar to the [approved answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64519702/15809154), but `InArray` is simplified and inlined.

```
type IsUnique<A extends readonly unknown[]> =
  A extends readonly [infer X, ...infer Rest]
    ? X extends Rest[number]
      ? [never, 'Encountered value with duplicates:', X] // false
      : IsUnique<Rest>
    : true;

type IsInArray<A extends readonly unknown[], X> = X extends A[number] ? true : false;
type TestA = IsUnique<["A","B","C"]>; // true
type TestB = IsUnique<["A","B","B"]>; // [never, "Encountered value with duplicates:", "B"]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgzjAdgQQE6oIYgDzKhAD2AkQBM4pUINSB7RAGxCgFdEBrRWgd0QG0AugBooADQB8UALxj8REuSjI%20iFgFsARhFQCoAfijBULaAC4oAMwwM4EANwBYAFChIsOAFVEASwCOJ3DliMgoqGnomVg4uXkFJKWcoJSCFUOo6RmY%20b0QLbTERADpinLzUKAAlCDhgAUSk-XckNEwcKpqRCRSQw2MIeobGlQgAN20RAHIAUUQAY1o2YipSKBHrEyhub2AACyhSFjAGb1mMYjhTCc66p0Gk83gvPwD24HEBqHMjE0cnZ1doAAVarAACM0ncT38EGwfAARMg4UI4QAhJFwgDCcIE4jsUAA9PjeiZ-uAgSCAEwQx4%20aGwhHotHItE4vGEqDDMaoERwmbzRbaCArNYMDZbXb7Q7HU7nUxIqCo7FAA)

Comment: This dosent work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another readable (I hope) solution.

```
type ExcludeByIndex<T extends readonly unknown[], I extends keyof T & (number | string)> = {
    [X in keyof T]: X extends (`${I}` | I) ? never : T[X]
}

export type ExcludeNotUnique<T extends readonly unknown[]> = {
    [I in keyof T]-?: T[I] extends ExcludeByIndex<T, I>[number] ? never : T[I]
}


const ids = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5] as const;

type UniqueIds = ExcludeNotUnique<typeof ids>;

function DummyUniqueIdsTest(): UniqueIds[number] {
    return ids[Math.random()];
}
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Sadly this only works b/c of the `as const` and the `type of ids`. Only really good for specific uses and less of a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

What I do currently is wrap my function argument to be a JavaScript Set,
then i use values with `Array.from(mySet)`.

```
function someFn(map: List, keysSet: Set<keyof List>) {
  const uniqueValue = Array.from(keysSet);
}
```

This way even if you're duplicating, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: He asked for a type not a function

Answer (score -2):

Typescript only performs compile time inspection. Modifying the array at runtime cannot be detected by Typescript.
On the other hand, you might want to use the Set class to prevent duplicate items from being inserted (but won't raise errors unless you check return value). But that won't raise compile time errors.

Comment: The question doesn't ask for compiletime duplicate detection - and it is possible to declare readonly types in TypeScript

Comment: If it doesn't ask for compile time duplicate detection, what is it asking for?

Comment: Sorry - that was a typo - it wasn't asking for *runtime* duplicate detection

Comment: Read-only does not prevent adding items to an array/set either. It prevents direct assignments, but calling mutating methods on an object is not protected by read-only

Comment: See this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBFCyIEEBOSCGIoF4ZIqgJgPYB2ANhgM7BICWxA5gNoC6A3FAFADGJVUAtohToAXHCFoM2RgCIAZoUIyANFBkAjVEhnMoqClB7EqrDh0HJJAOjABXCgAsAFDIcRSpJQEp25ieit+VDAnADcsAD5DXkJSCCtPehc3D28fTgthECsKUhouCCcARlUi9IB6coB5AGs-SwCKMDyC4tKK8v5bYFRgCAMAWigKQihiQmAoQhqrTjMjPkzJACYxeAapKFlNbVV5RR1fJfRlm3tnDS0ZdPqs09z8wpKoMvZK2tuVnObHtpeOro9PqDYajcaTaazMwcIA

Comment: That seems like a new feature.

Answer (score -2):

A workaround for the people who wants a simple solution:
If you create an object, a duplicate key will throw error like:

```
const anObject = {
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    2: 0, //will throw error
}
```

But the problem is, keys are string, you can't save anything in the keys other than string.

```
const anObject = {
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    "2": 0, //will throw error
    "foo": 0
}
```

If you are not trying to have a unique array with both number and strings, this might work for you.
And then, you can use the object like:

```
Object.keys(anObject)
```

, and use it as array.

Answer (score -7):

Typescript refers only on type, not value, moreover, on runtime arrays it will do nothing.

Comment: This clarification isn't that helpful - for example you can have `readonly` types and use the `as const` keyword.