# Python type hint for collection with elements that should occur once

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I'd like to construct a type hint for a sequence of string literals which could accept each of the literals but any literal couldn't occur more than once in the sequence.

I've tried to look for existing solutions and in the standard docs but so far without luck.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```py
from typing import Literal, Sequence

MyValues = Literal["a", "b", "c"]

def my_function(values: Sequence[MyValues]):
    pass

my_function(values=[]) 
my_function(values=["a", "b"])  
my_function(values=["a", "b", "a"])  # should fail type checking
```

In the above example all function calls pass type checking, which is expected. However during a third case I'd like to see an error which tells me that the literal `"a"` occurs more than once in the sequence.

I'm not sure if it's even possible but I'm curious if anyone has an idea how to workaround this issue.

Obviously I can filter out duplicates in the function body, but in this case the main idea is to catch such mistakes during development time.

Comment: Would it make sense to make `values` a `Set` rather than a `Sequence`?

Comment: The *contents* of a list are not a type-level feature. You would have to define your own type which carries a guaranteed of element uniqueness, then make it that type's responsibility to enforce that guarantee.

Comment: Also note that typehinting in python does nothing at runtime. It won't throw an error if you pass it an argument which doesn't fit.

Comment: @Mous Syntactic sugar is something that could be expressed in terms of other, more primitive, syntax. (Decorator syntax, for example, which is just a shorthand for function application.) Type hints simply don't have any run-time effect.

Comment: I'll edit my comment appropriately.

Comment: Python's type system has no support for this, and only pretty exotic type systems would support it.

Comment: I don't want to guarantee anything using type hints, I think that is obvious. I just want to aid developers during dev time, so auto-completion would only display those literals which haven't been passed to the sequence already.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga seems like TypeScript somehow supports this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57016728/is-there-a-way-to-define-type-for-array-with-unique-items-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want your code to throw an error, you'll need to check it at runtime. Contrary to popular belief, typehints don't actually raise an Exception at runtime if they are passed the wrong argument. For example, no error will be thrown in the following code:

```
from typing import Sequence

def foo(bar: Sequence):
    pass

foo(0) #this is an integer, and yet doesn't error
```

For your code to throw an error, you need something going on inside your function, such as:

```py
def my_function(values):
    if len(set(values))!=len(values):
        raise Exception("Duplicate value in argument")
```

Comment: Presumably, the OP is asking about using a static type checker

Comment: @Mous thank you for your answer. However as I said I'm not looking for runtime checks, I'm just curious if I the type checker could warn the developers about duplicate literals.

Comment: You could make a decorator that enforces typechecking