# How to restrict array items using union type with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

There is some event type: For example,

```
interface Event {
  type: 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
  value: string;
}

interface App {
  elements: Event[];
}
```

It's not bad, but I could do the following thing:

```
const app: App = {
  elements: [
    { type: 'a', value: '1' },
    { type: 'a', value: '2' },
  ],
}
```

But I need that elements array contains objects with uniq type (only one item with type 'a', only one item with type 'b', etc). How could I do it in TypeScript? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Is there a way to define type for array with unique items in typescript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57016728/is-there-a-way-to-define-type-for-array-with-unique-items-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64519702/157247) to your situation (your union would be of distinct `SomeEvent` types, which you can generate from your existing type). It's complicated and I couldn't do it in the time I gave it, but it may be possible.

It would simpler, though, to use an object instead of an array, keyed by the type: `elements: {a: { value: "1" } }`. (If you need to get an array from it at some point, you can always use [`Object.values(theApp.elements)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get it, but you can easily [loop through objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object), not just arrays.)

```typescript
interface SomeEvent {
  type: 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
  value: string;
}

interface App {
  elements: Partial<{
    [key in SomeEvent["type"]]: Omit<SomeEvent, "type"> & { type: key};
  }>
}
```

That uses the type as an object key, and requires the object assigned to it to have the same value as `typd`. (I used the name `SomeEvent` instead of `Event` to avoid confusing with DOM events.)

Then this works:

```typescript
const app1: App = {
  elements: {
    a: { type: 'a', value: '1' },
    b: { type: 'b', value: '2' },
  },
};
```

but this has an error as desired:

```typescript
const app2: App = {
  elements: {
    a: { type: 'a', value: '1' },
    a: { type: 'a', value: '2' }, // An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name in strict mode.
  },
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2ECiA3CcZAbwFgAoZZMATwAcIAuZAcjheQB9WAjD7lghYBuClTxwANgFcmyAM5gooAOajyAXwoVQkWIhQBBOnRJjkESRGzh5zAApwoYYFIA8ZSlWQBtANYQNMigaFi4BOA+AES0DFEAuvHMAPKYwGBuGNj4hGAANMgx9BBRAHzIAGQk1MXMATQa6lQapRRa5BQA9J3IAOroUH7yFAjoIIrIcCYAjMzGpgC8Zl6W1rl2y96TzMQ1DMxsLAUSMnIs0xwaeeZUPDt7Z3zHUrIHAEyX115XbepdPTgoFABpN5MgACYQeTAKAQcEjMYTKZ0N5zEzIJaeKirGxgDZY7xwe6xM7sZ6nA4XZA-LxUInVEkHMnIE6vVgfakFbrIQwgZDoHgAKwgCDAyEk6WgUmQCDgIBA6DFAAs4ARkJhpJIXHQrMg6MCGM5gFDkAB3dJK6hKlDyODYZAgO0oEKKZSi9XoSEAOnMNMaQA)

Comment: I found a way to add `type` back to the objects in `elements`. If you don't see that above, hit refresh, it was a ninja edit. :-)

Comment: elements is array, sorry ( Object is not possible

Comment: @malcoauri - Then I don't think you can do it, except with a fixed-length tuple as jeremy-denis points out. But I'm curious: Why can't it be an object? You can always use `Object.values` when you need an array.

Comment: @malcoauri - Actually, you may be able to do it by adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64519702/157247). But it's complicated. But I'm still curious about the array requirement.

Answer (score 0):

one way can be to create an interface for Event with different type a, b or c

you can create an interface that will say your elements property can have one instance of each type

```
interface EventFilter {
  elements: [EventA?, EventB?, EventC?];
}
```

The limitation of this solution is that element should be added in the order defined in EventFilter

```
interface Event {
  type: 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
  value: string;
}

interface EventA extends Event {
  type: 'a';
}

interface EventB extends Event {
  type: 'b';
}

interface EventC extends Event {
  type: 'c';
}

interface EventFilter {
  elements: [EventA?, EventB?, EventC?];
}

const app: EventFilter = {
  elements: [ 
    { type: 'a', value: '1' },
    { type: 'b', value: '1' } 
  ],
}
```

unfortunately, you will have to list all authorised combine to be able to have a flexible array with element in any order

```
interface EventFilter {
  elements: [EventA?, EventB?, EventC?] | [EventA?, EventC?, EventB?] 
            | [EventB?, EventA?, EventC?] | [EventB?, EventC?, EventA?]
            | [EventC?, EventA?, EventB?] | [EventC?, EventB?, EventA?];
}

const app: EventFilter = {
  elements: [ 
    { type: 'c', value: '1' },
    { type: 'a', value: '1' },
  ],
}
```