# function spread parameters should not be repeated in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, parameters

I am creating a function that takes some roles in an Enum, I want the parameters not to be repeated.

```js
type Role = 'ADMIN' | 'GUEST'

function roleMiddleware(...roles: Role[]){
  // some logic
}
roleMiddleware('ADMIN', 'ADMIN'); // I shouldn't be able to do that
```

Is this achievable ? and if so how should I type the parameters of that function to achieve such behavior?

Comment: You're passing strings instead of the enum, and if I copy your code into the playground I get errors that aren't relevant to the problem.

Comment: the enum is defined in my prisma schema and it creates the type `type Role = 'ADMIN' | 'GUEST'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking some inspiration from [Is there a way to define type for array with unique items in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57016728/is-there-a-way-to-define-type-for-array-with-unique-items-in-typescript), we can achieve the following:

```
type Invalid<T> = Error & { __errorMessage: T };

type Valid<Roles extends Role[]> = {
  [K in keyof Roles]: unknown extends {
    [P in keyof Roles]: K extends P ? never : Roles[P] extends Roles[K] ? unknown : never;
  }[keyof Roles]
    ? Invalid<[Roles[K], "is repeated"]>
    : Roles[K]
}

function roleMiddleware<Roles extends Role[]>(...roles: Valid<Roles>) { ... }
```

For a detailed in-depth explanation, see linked question above.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w1pXXW)