# Typescript: type with unique values for first and second members in tuple (kind of dictionary for theme's colors)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, type-inference, conditional-types, recursive-type

Having an object for theme's colors:

```
themeColors = {
  primary: ['#fff', '#000'],
  secondary: ['#DDD', '#333'],
  error: ['#CCC', '#444']
}
```

We can assign type like this:

```
themeColor: Record<string, [string; string]>
```

How to add restriction first and second of tupel should be unique?
I mean

```
themeColors = {
  primary: ['#fff', '#000'],
  secondary: ['#fff', '#333'],
}
```

or

```
themeColors = {
  primary: ['#fff', '#000'],
  secondary: ['#DDD', '#000']
}
```

shouldn't pass type checking, becouse have duplication ('#fff' in first case, '#000' in second case)

I belive it sould be close to this approach

[Is there a way to define type for array with unique items in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57016728/is-there-a-way-to-define-type-for-array-with-unique-items-in-typescript)

Comment: The first and second tuples in your question are kind of unique. It just that they share a value. Is sharing a value what you want to avoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a helper function to the inference and validation:

```
const themeColors = colors({
  primary: ['#fff', '#000'],
  secondary: ['#DDD', '#333'],
  error: ['#CCC', '#444']
} as const);
```

Here's what that function would look like:

```
function colors<C extends Record<string, readonly [string, string]>>(c: {
    [K in keyof C]: C[K] extends readonly [infer A, infer B]
        ? readonly [A, B]
            & (A extends Omit<C, K>[keyof Omit<C, K>][0] ? never : {})
            & (B extends Omit<C, K>[keyof Omit<C, K>][1] ? never : {})
        : C[K];
}) { return c }
```

We go through each of the entries and check if the first or second string already exist in the other entries. If it is, we intersect the type with `never`, otherwise, an empty object type `{}` (which basically does nothing).

You won't get a *super* helpful error, but hey, it's still an error. If you moved the checks to before `readonly [A, B]`, then TypeScript won't be able to infer the original type of `C` and everything will break. This is the only method I have found which retains inference while still validating the input correctly. See the linked playground below with some examples.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N7ovRN)

Comment: Grate, it works!

Comment: The most unobvious thing - is why we should return empty object - not [A, B] cortege or something else.
Can you advise me on the course or book for deep learning TS? Because I didn't find any article about this case and I fill I have gaps in my understanding of approaches.

Comment: @МихаилБобрышев It's actually all in the documentation, but you have to put all the pieces together yourself. For a walkthrough of that, I recommend https://type-level-typescript.com/. Other than that, everything you need is in the docs - bugs and issues with TypeScript itself or its behavior/design are probably documented as GitHub issues.