# How to type any order of specific strings in array

Tags: typescript

If one has a string array say,

```
const myArray = ["apple", "banana"]
```

How would one type this in TypeScript so that is satisfies any/all of the following:

```
["banana", "apple"]
["banana"]
["apple"]
```

I thought I could do something like:

```
const myArray = ["apple", "banana"] as const
type MyArrayType = typeof myArray;
```

But that doesn't seem to work as expected.

Comment: `("apple" | "banana")[]`? Should `[]` be valid? Should `["apple", "banana", "carrot"]`? `["apple", "banana", "apple"]`?

Comment: Correct. `[]` and anything other than a subset of the original array should be invalid.

Comment: How big will your set of strings be?  If it's more than about five or six then the union-of-all-possible-valid-tuples is, while easy to generate, too unwieldy to be useful.

Comment: I apologize if I'm using the wrong terminology. The length of array (of strings) wouldn't be more than say, six. Duplicates should be disallowed.

Comment: So does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAdyvN) meet your needs? Note that for six elements, you get a union of ~2K members.  The compiler can handle that. For seven elements that jumps to ~14K... again, the compiler can handle that, but you might notice slowdowns.  For eight, it's more than 100K and TypeScript will probably explode.  If this approach works for you I can write up an answer explaining; otherwise, what am I missing? (Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. Use it like this

```
const myArray = ["apple", "banana"] as const
type MyArrayType = Array<typeof myArray[number]>

const test: MyArrayType = ["apple"]
const test1: MyArrayType = ["banana"]
const test2: MyArrayType = ["banana", "apple"]
const test3: MyArrayType = ["banana", "apple", "kiwi"] // error
```

For uniqueness check you can use the type with one of the examples here [Is there a way to define type for array with unique items in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57016728/is-there-a-way-to-define-type-for-array-with-unique-items-in-typescript)