# Avoid duplicate in array of union types or object with a key of the same union types

Tags: typescript

I have the function named `process` where I want to spread an array of `UserRole` or `UserRoleInObject`. My current code is working but doesn't avoid duplicate `UserRole` in array.

```
type UserRole = "admin" | "seller" | "customer";

type UserRoleInOject = {
  role: UserRole;
};

function process(
  ...userTypes: Array<UserRole | UserRoleInOject>
): void {
  //...
}

process();
process("admin", "seller", "customer"); // should works - no duplicate role
process("admin", { role: "seller" }, { role: "admin" }); // should not works - duplicate role
process({ role: "admin" }, { role: "seller" }, { role: "customer" }); // should works - no duplicate role
process({ role: "admin" }, { role: "admin" }, "customer"); // should not works - duplicate role
```

My question is: how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you want to check a string [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) array for duplicates using type checks with some (additional) rules. These are the cases we're looking for:

- `"some role"` and `"some role"` are duplicates (`UserRole` <-> `UserRole`).
- `{role: "some role"}` and `{role: "some role"}` are duplicates (`UserRoleInObject`  <-> `UserRoleInObject`).
- `{role: "some role"}` and `"some role"` and vice versa are duplicates (`UserRoleInObject` <-> `UserRole`).

```
type UserRole = "admin" | "seller" | "customer";

type UserRoleInObject = {
  role: UserRole;
};
```

There already are some good solutions for literal array duplicates on this site (See [Is there a way to define type for array with unique items in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57016728/is-there-a-way-to-define-type-for-array-with-unique-items-in-typescript)). We just need to add some tweaks for string literal to object literal duplicate detection.

First define `process()` with a [generic parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) so we can infer the literal array.

```
function process<T extends (UserRole | UserRoleInObject)[]>(
  ...userTypes: UniqueRoles<T>
): void {
  // Your function implementation here
}
```

---

Next we need some recursive helper types to ensure *unique* arguments.

```
type UniqueRoles<T extends unknown[]> = T extends readonly [
  infer U, // <- infer the first item in the array
  ...infer Rest,
]
  ? RoleInArray<Rest, U> extends true // <- Check if there is a duplicate
    ? never // <- Yes? Return 'never'. You could also return some custom error literal
    : readonly [U, ...UniqueRoles<Rest>] // <- No? Check for the rest of the array
  : T;
```

Now the actual duplicate detection logic:

```
type RoleInArray<T extends unknown[], R> = T extends readonly [
  R,
  ...infer _Rest,
]
  ? true // <- Check for "equality" on the first inferred item
  : T extends readonly [{ role: R }, ...infer _Rest] 
  ? true // <- Check if T contains a role of 'UserRoleInOject' shape
  : R extends { role: infer U } // <- Inverted check if R is of 'UserRoleInOject' shape
  ? T extends readonly [U, ...infer _Rest]
    ? true // <- Check if the array contains a matching string literal
    : T extends readonly [infer _, ...infer Rest]
    ? RoleInArray<Rest, R> // <- Check for the rest of the array
    : false // <- No duplicates
  : T extends readonly [infer _, ...infer Rest]
  ? RoleInArray<Rest, R> // <- Check for the rest of the array
  : false; // <- No duplicates
```

---

Here are your given examples.

```
// Examples
process(); // valid
process("admin", "seller", "customer"); // valid
process("admin", { role: "seller" }, { role: "admin" }); // error
process({ role: "admin" }, { role: "seller" }, { role: "customer" }); // valid
process({ role: "admin" }, { role: "admin" }, "customer"); // error
```

Some more test cases (all invalid)

```
process("admin", "admin");
process({ role: "admin" }, { role: "admin" });
process("admin", { role: "admin" });
process({ role: "admin" }, "admin");
process("seller", "admin", { role: "admin" });
process("seller", { role: "customer" }, { role: "seller" });
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgJQPYBtoF4oCICGAJgLYCWAdrlAD54LqaJW24DGArnMKsUrgNwAoQaEiwEKDBACS5APIAjAFYRWwKDgDegqFERSAXOKRpMQgL5DBAM3bk1pVOShh9rCHDgAeACpQIAB7AEOSEcFAAFPAmUjTGkpiyiipqAJQA2gC6AHwROlAAdEWcSD7gHkYw5KQAjuwQph6+2YKpRgBuqKSEUNq6APT9UACaqOyIULb2wI7OpMRgmLzkwPgzTlAAFkgQgubCotBVtfWN3n6BwaHhdgDW5KgA7uRZ2RpQF0EhYXoQRE7oEBQdL5CjWJCwAA0+SKBTBEOQHmA0My+QA-FBGrIAIKIRD4EBeRFcSGwN6Xb7hYCIer5XQY8gQdpIOlQIyIP6EAFA9IwUmw451BpSbzE4DZVG6Iw+KyHTFSHF4gm+fxfa5QO4PZ5ZUnIN44T5XH4c-7kQHA-LIaG6WHwiYAfTFKPRUGptKlH1VRvCJq5Zp5mj0hkxUHM-KKdqgjqRmSgLrduw9yC9lN6QcwRkjMFDLsNqd93OBfMKEfI4IdYsluigGITrOlKfVBf9wMj9vDcLLCJjrIxWPIuPxhKdmJa1bZk3w6AQ+QbFKbnML6TbHcjlZd-cHypHetnk+nECsgygAFEAvgFpg4IJXKh3J4IqkhLf73AIgQSBRcKTcPRGN+8A4LgeD4J8bzcDw3w-MhKFJQN9AzOgIAYPhQzg9MICMaCv1DMCX0giJ4ODbDKDQtMEMwpCUKYMiiMQthOG4XgaPMPCIIfOjKJIqgw3I4iiBgnifyApjQKsfCH24n8BK-Ni7wIzisJk0jeMUvBlJ4uTX3fDT0IopTPxUrSFIwgzBLI7jjMkv8+GkwyALU7jcOfdioJspg9OIkSQJYzz6PczShCAA)