# TypeScript: use object type to create type for array of objects with unique values of object keys

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an object:
`const myObj = { key1: "value1", key2: "value2" }`

I need a type for an array that will guarantee an output array like this: `const arr: ArrayWithUniqueValues = [{commonKey: "value1"}, {commonKey: "value2"}]`

TypeScript should not allow using one value more than once and should check that all values from myObj were used.
Is there a way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Do this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57016728/is-there-a-way-to-define-type-for-array-with-unique-items-in-typescript

Comment: `type ArrayWithUniqueValues = Array<{ commonKey: string }>;

const myObj = { key1: "value1", key2: "value2" };

const arr: ArrayWithUniqueValues = [
  { commonKey: myObj.key1 },
  { commonKey: myObj.key2 },
];`  i am not sure is this what you want , if it is then for more genialize block use loop upto the length of input obj .  else let me know