# How to get the values or an object in the order of its type in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider the following interface:

```
interface Foo {
  bar: string;
  baz: number;
}
```

I want to get the values of a `Foo` in the order of the above definition, not the order of assignment, ie:

```
magicFn({bar: 'a', baz: 0}) === magicFn({baz: 0, bar: 'a'}) // ['a', 0]
```

My naive approach was to use `Object.values()` but that ignores the order of the interface (not so surprising as interfaces are not Javascript entities).

I have seen an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13267) about it, but it has been locked by MS...

**EDIT:**

I don't want any guarantee of property order. I want to have a function which retrieves the values in the order as a given interface defined it.

Comment: You don't have any type (interface) info at runtime

Comment: interfaces don't exist at runtime. There are some alternatives: [Get keys of a Typescript interface as array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909566)

Comment: Please note I don't want an object propery order quarantee, I just want to retrieve the values in a given order based on a given interface.

Comment: what is your use case? There may be a better way to achieve what you're after?

Answer (score 1):

Property order is not guaranteed by javascript, and Typescript is a superset of javascript.
I suggest you use a different data structure that preserves order, a `Map` or array

Comment: *"Property order is not guaranteed by javascript*" is not exactly true for ES6+

Comment: Property order *is* guaranteed to a significant extent in most cases, in modern environments, if you use the right object iteration methods.

Comment: And not related to question above

Comment: That is exactly the reason why I need a `magicFn` :)