# How to check if a string is one of Interface's properties ? (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
var attributeStr = 'scaleX'

interface CSSTransformsAttr{
   scaleX: number,
   scaleY: number,
   skewX: number,
   skewY: number,
   translateX: number,
   translateY: number
}
```

How to check if the value of `attributeStr` is equal to a key in `CSSTransformsAttr` ?

## Why do i ask this?

I want to extends the `CSSStyleDeclaration` with `CSSTransformsAttr`. 
If `k` is key of `CSSTransformsAttr` which is `'scaleX' | 'scaleY' | 'skewX' | 'skewY' | 'translateX' | 'translateY'`, i want to do something different than line (1). See below.

```js
function setStyleAttributes(attrs: { [ k in keyof ( CSSStyleDeclaration & CSSTransformsAttr )]?: any }): void {
    if (attrs !== undefined) {
            Object.keys(attrs).forEach((key: string) => {
                /// how to check if 'key' is from the CSSTransfomsAttr not CSSStyleDeclaration ?
                /// ...
            this.htmlElement.style[key]=  attrs[key]; // (1) if key in keyof CSSStyleDeclaration
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your post and include the code in the image as text? Please copy and paste it here from your editor, instead of using a screenshot.

Comment: Sure ! wait a minute.

Comment: please have a look, sir!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply checking `keyof` is only going to work at compile time, not runtime. You need to store all the keys in an array and check if your value exists in it. This can be done manually:

```js
interface CSSMatrixTransforms{
   scaleX: number,
   scaleY: number,
   skewX: number,
   skewY: number,
   translateX: number,
   translateY: number
};
type CSSMatrixTransformsKey = keyof CSSMatrixTransforms;
const matrixKeys: CSSMatrixTransformsKey[] = [
   'scaleX',
   'scaleY',
   'skewX',
   'skewY',
   'translateX',
   'translateY'
];
```

Alternatively, you can create a "dummy" object that implements your interface and then call [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) on it.

```js
interface CSSMatrixTransforms{
   scaleX: number,
   scaleY: number,
   skewX: number,
   skewY: number,
   translateX: number,
   translateY: number
}
type CSSMatrixTransformsKey = keyof CSSMatrixTransforms;
const dummy: CSSMatrixTransforms = {
   scaleX: 0,
   scaleY: 0,
   skewX: 0,
   skewY: 0,
   translateX: 0,
   translateY: 0
}
const matrixKeys: CSSMatrixTransformsKey[] = Object.keys(dummy) as CSSMatrixTransformsKey[];
```

Finally, in your code, check if your `key` exists in the `matrixKeys` array:

```js
function setStyleAttributes(attrs: { [ k in keyof ( CSSStyleDeclaration & CSSTransformsAttr )]?: any }): void {
    if (attrs !== undefined) {
            Object.keys(attrs).forEach((key: string) => {
                if(matrixKeys.includes(key)) {
                    this.htmlElement.style[key] = attrs[key];
                }

        });
    }
}
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909566/get-keys-of-a-typescript-interface-as-array-of-strings) out as well.

Comment: Thank you! Wondering if they can make it as a feature for Typescript in the future.

Comment: Yes, that would be very helpful. For the moment, this is the way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

With the `keyof` operator e.g.

```
var attributeStr: keyof CSSMatrixTransforms = 'scaleX' // ok

var attributeStr: keyof CSSMatrixTransforms = 'scaleX1' // wrong
```

Comment: this is what i tried: 
```var randomStr = randomString(); 
var attributeStr: keyof CSSMatrixTransforms = randomStr
```

i got failed compile: 
`Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"scaleX" | "scaleY" | "skewX" | "skewY" | "translateX" | "translateY"'.`

Comment: You have to define the return type of `randomString` with the same type as `attributeStr`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the code shown below, I had to add the `as` to cast them but at least I no longer use the `any` Type anywhere now.

```js
// we need to exclude readonly & function properties (since they're not writable props)
export type CSSStyleDeclarationReadonly = 'length' | 'parentRule' | 'getPropertyPriority' | 'getPropertyValue' | 'item' | 'removeProperty' | 'setProperty';
export type CSSStyleDeclarationWritable = keyof Omit<CSSStyleDeclaration, CSSStyleDeclarationReadonly>;

Object.keys(this.stylingCss as CSSStyleDeclaration).forEach(cssStyleKey => {
  this.elem!.style[cssStyleKey as CSSStyleDeclarationWritable] = this.stylingCss[cssStyleKey as CSSStyleDeclarationWritable];
});
```

There you go, no more errors and now it does Type checking correctly