# How to get the property name / key name of an interface as a string in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Currently working with Slacks API and there are instances where I send JSON requests with strings, and these strings return at a later point as property names.

I would like have an interface and send one of its property names as a string. And then have the returning object correctly typed. I dont want to have to deal with "magic strings" or constants that I have to keep in sync with the interface.

Quick example:

```js
// This is the request I send out to Slack
const request = {
    actionId: "specialProperty"
};

// And Slack might give me this object at a later point
const incomingWebhook = {
    specialProperty: "Value I want to read"
}
```

I can fairly easily get typing for this with an interface

```js
interface SpecialPropertyInterface {
  specialProperty: string;
}
```

My issue is that this interface is bound to the string that I send out.

Is there a way for me to get the key/property "specialProperty" from my SpecialPropertyInterface as a string?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909566/get-keys-of-a-typescript-interface-as-array-of-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up resolving my issue by using "keyof".
Not optimal, but I get a typesafe string that is based on a interface property.

I had two nested keys, so I split them up into two interfaces and and used keyof to get the string of the property for each of them.

```js
export interface HoursBlock {
  hours: HoursBlockAction;
}

export interface HoursBlockAction {
  hoursAction: {
    // eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
    selected_option: {
      value: string;
    };
  };
}

...

// This string will only be valid if you write the name of the property.
const hoursBlockId: keyof HoursBlock = "hours";
const hoursActionId: keyof HoursBlockAction = "hoursAction";

// If you type a different string you will trigger an error.
// Type '"wrong"' is not assignable to type '"hours"'.ts(2322)
const wrongHoursBlockId: keyof HoursBlock = "wrong";
```

Comment: If you don't want to split the interfaces, you can write the following: `const hoursActionId: keyof HoursBlock['hours'] = "hoursAction";`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt.

First, add `as const` as a suffix to the declaration of your `request` object:

```
const request = {
    actionId: "specialProperty"
} as const;
```

As a consequence, the type of the `actionId` property is a literal (`"specialProperty"`) instead of a `string`:

```
type RequestActionId = typeof request["actionId"] // "specialProperty"
```

Now, we can use it in a [mapped index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```
type SpecialPropertyInterface = {
  [propName in RequestActionId]: string; // specialProperty: string
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwI4FcHRgXhgbwFAyEwCGwUAluAJIAmAXDAEQQAOCw5xANgApwhs4UAJ6M8AXxIQYoSFADcePCLYwASsjTQAgmUphaWGCoQgAZvE3ooAbUakK1GowC6SkzADKbDtz4CEIWEqMChAs1IEI3xCGxZ+FgA5YgBbKPIwdSsdPScXBmg4DIBzRXEgA)