# Is it possible to map the property names of a type into a array type?

Tags: typescript

Given the following type

```
type A = {
    foo: string
    bar: number
}
```

is it possible to create a mapped/conditional type such that

```
type APropertyNameList = MapToProperyNameList<A>

let l1: APropertyNameList = ["foo", "bar] //correct
let l2: APropertyNameList = ["foo", "boom"] //compile error
let l3: APropertyNameList = ["foo", "bar", "bar"] //compile error 2x bar
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get keys of a Typescript interface as array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909566/get-keys-of-a-typescript-interface-as-array-of-strings)

Answer (score 0):

```js
type A = {
    foo: string
    bar: number
}

type MyKeys<T> = (keyof T)[];

const l1: MyKeys<A> = ['foo', 'bar'] // Correct
const l2: MyKeys<A> = ['foo', 'boom'] // Error
```

Comment: well not exactly. This is also possible `const l3: MyKeys<A> = ['foo', 'bar', 'bar'] // Correct`