# How to check if a var has the same elements as an interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I want to write a generic function that takes as input an interface and a variable as sees if the names and data types of the variable match that of the typeface. Or do something similar. But I can't find anything. How would I do this?

Comment: Could you post some code that you've tried that maybe illustrates exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: You might be looking for "User defined type guards" -> https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: duplication of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909566/get-keys-of-a-typescript-interface-as-array-of-strings]?

Comment: You cannot pass an `interface` as an argument to a function because typescript types do not exist at runtime.  If you are dealing with a `class` that `implements` an `interface` then you can use `instanceof`.  Otherwise, this cannot be handled in a generalized, generic way.