# Get Type keys in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Lets say we have this Type:

```
export type UsersSchema = {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
};
```

Is there a way to make this pseudo-code work:

`Object.keys(UsersSchema)` which would ideally yield: `['id', 'firstName', 'lastNight', 'email']`

Obviously `UsersSchema` is not a value, so the above does not work...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get keys of a Typescript interface as array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909566/get-keys-of-a-typescript-interface-as-array-of-strings)

Comment: There is no easy way. You can use third party library for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909566/get-keys-of-a-typescript-interface-as-array-of-strings . But, I don't know what about order guarantee

Comment: Do you want to have access to these values at runtime?

Answer (score 11):

The type doesn't exist at run time.

However, (leaning heavily on [this beautiful answer](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-692864087), which will require TS4.x because of its use of recursive conditional types), you can create a tuple type that enforces a tuple with the required names.

So:

```
type TupleUnion<U extends string, R extends string[] = []> = {
    [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never 
                ? [...R, S] 
                : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>, [...R, S]>;
}[U] & string[];


export type UsersSchema = {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
};

const allKeysOfUsersSchema: TupleUnion<keyof UsersSchema> = 
    ["id", "firstName", "lastName", "email"]; //OK

const wrongKeysOfUsersSchema: TupleUnion<keyof UsersSchema> = 
    ["monkey", "firstName", "lastName", "email"]; //error

const missingKeysOfUsersSchema: TupleUnion<keyof UsersSchema> = 
    ["id", "firstName", "lastName"]; //error

const tooManyKeysOfUsersSchema: TupleUnion<keyof UsersSchema> = 
    ["id", "firstName", "lastName", "email", "cat"]; //error
```

OK... so you'll have to maintain this separate tuple, manually, but at least if things change, the compiler will push you into remedial action, so type-safety is maintained.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhAqgOwJYHs0B4VQQAewEaAJgM5SXABOGaA5gDRQBKhJZVN9jTANoBdKAF4oIgHzioAbwBQASEEBlKIygphALigBRIgGNEcchHxtVM4qQrU0EAG4Q6UAPySAdD-ZXRevBIqJg4uIYmZhYoVlJsgj5eflCqwlIA3AoAvoLaUABkfAzMIpkKCsRgWHTAUKCQWpSulKpGABYQALYAhrKKUBrkemhwnQBGrpkDAGYYdLQAct2dEHq0xUxTUIjdi8urRQJbXd0YiGv8zJlZZUY4tFDdiIgA0hAglADy0yhN860dHqBBDIdDYPAAa3eWGmjWaAJOMgkggARBhyCi2CjZvNgEsVpioCidnsCViTmcUcJbvdagB3Og4JhvD7fX7w9onYHBMFhKEgGFw-6cnpIyQozo4fmE7FzUkQGUkvH7GUUxBUmloB6dDCUSgCFlfH5-Foi7rc0GhSHQ2Hs4WA7pi1HomU4%20WK3bKgnU8p3LW1YBYLAAWW6aBAhrZJoRQNgIJC4Nw-MFdtNDqdaIxWLdXoVWKV%20LzRLVMqM3WAGvKQA)

Answer (score 5):

in addition to **hwasurr** answer you probably need to put the keys in parenthesis to get the right type

the array of keys:

```
type Keys = (keyof UsersSchema)[]
// ("id" | "firstName" | "lastName" | "email")[]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `keyof` type operator.

```js
export type UsersSchema = {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
};

type Keys = keyof UsersSchema // "id" | "firstName" | "lastName" | "email"
```

Comment: Is there a way to use them as value now? `fetch("https://my-url?filter=id,firstName,lastName,email")`?

Comment: @MatthisKohli As far as i know, it's impossible to use type as a value. However, you can use this key type to create type-checking functions