# Can we create an array of strings from a type/interface keys?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Suppose there's `type` or `interface` named `NumberLookupCriteria`:

```
type NumberLookupCriteria = {
  dialCode: string;
  phoneNumber: string;
}
```

or

```
interface NumberLookupCriteria {
  dialCode: string;
  phoneNumber: string;
}
```

Can we somehow manage to get all the `keys` as an JS array of strings like this:

```
const keys = ['dialCode','phoneNumber']
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't because types and interfaces doesn't exists at runtime.

A workaround can be the use of class

[View ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/MYGwhgzhAEByCuBbARgUwE4BkD22DW8ADgMLoCWALhmWNAN4BQ0z0w2AdhBevMBdugAUTFqPSowAEw4gAntEk0QxbJNQAuaF3LsA5tAC8AIiMAaEaObipM+YQAWHVAhQZN2snsMnzogJT0AL4MwQxsnBTQYOjoYLIA0qjyBtCCAPLIAFaofAB0eEkQguyoAO5wSGhYuAQk5FTkYIJ+LQxhHBDYIKi5INi6gtGxCUl+beFc0FRcmi5VOPhEpJTUtCmMzIpgyqoa0EZgZiIOTnNu+8hGIeMdXT19A9MUfkA)

```
class NumberLookupCriteria {
    constructor(
        readonly dialCode: string ="",
        readonly phoneNumber: string ="",
    ) {}
}

const arrayKey = (Object.keys(new NumberLookupCriteria()))

console.log(arrayKey) // ["dialCode", "phoneNumber"]

const test: NumberLookupCriteria = {
  dialCode: "a",
  phoneNumber: "b"
} 
// OK

const test: NumberLookupCriteria = {
  dialCode: "a"
} 
// KO: Property 'phoneNumber' is missing in type '{ dialCode: string; }' but required in type 'NumberLookupCriteria'
```

There is many post about it:

[Get keys of a Typescript interface as array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909566/get-keys-of-a-typescript-interface-as-array-of-strings)
[Get Type keys in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66565322/get-type-keys-in-typescript)