# TS: How to extract keys from an interface and create type union

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm sorry for the bad title, I'm not sure how to describe the situation and maybe that's why I still haven't found the solution

i have an interface

```
interface Fields {
  name: string
  age: number
}
```

and I would like to extract the keys to create a type, for example

```
type FieldList = ?

// expected result
// type FieldList = 'name' | 'age'
```

and at another time I would like to use the extracted type to create an array

```
const list: FieldList = ['name', 'age']
```

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wRpyEm)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get keys of a Typescript interface as array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909566/get-keys-of-a-typescript-interface-as-array-of-strings)

Comment: You need union type from another Interface
`type FieldsKeys = keyof Fields;` 
`type FieldList = FieldsKeys[];`

Check [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwM5QLxQN4FgBQUUAdgIYC2EAXFKsAE5zEDmBRpz1JAruQEYR6BAL4ECoSLAQoAMnDqYoACgDWEEAHsAZlKRoAlAG0AugQD0ZqBOjw9chVgDkZSo6gAfKI44RHY-ADGGsQKiPLANLay4YqGAEQuEHEANFBxPilpqBqUwAAWTMxxpvgEQA)

Comment: @pilchard no, it's not what i need.

Comment: It had all the same info as the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two questions (or perhaps three).

### How to get the keys of a type?

```js
type FieldList = keyof Fields;
```

`FieldList` is now a *string literal union* – `'name' | 'age'`;

### How to get an array containing the keys of a type?

That's not possible – you can't "materialize" a type into a value.

### How to get an array type which can only contain keys of another type?

That's just `FieldList[]`.

```js
const list: FieldList[] = ['name', 'age']; // ok

const badList: FieldList[] = ['address']; // error
```

Comment: the third answer is what i need, `get an array type which can only contain keys of another type`, but would there be any way to define this in just a single line? because this is a function parameter, [example](https://i.ibb.co/G5Gk01J/Captura-de-Tela-2021-05-28-a-s-18-14-20.png)

Comment: What do you mean by _in just a single line_? From the example, I understand that you can call `removeErrors(['age', 'name'])`.

Comment: `Array<keyof Fields>` works fine, do you see anything better?

Comment: thanks for all the help, [here is the final result](https://tsplay.dev/NVnxxN)