# How to get a list of keys of generic type (TypeScript)?

Tags: typescript

How to get a list of keys from a generic object type?

generic Class:

```
export class GenericExample<T>{
   
 private _keys: string[];

 constructor()
 {
      this.keys = // all keys of generic type T
 }

  get keys(obj: T[])
  {
    return this._keys;
  }
}
```

example usage with interface:

```
export interface someInterface { foo: string; bar: string; };
export class someClass { id: number; name: string; };

let example1 = new GenericExample<someType>();
example1.getKeys([]) // output: ["foo", "bar" ]
```

example usage with class:

```
let example2= new GenericExample<someClass>();
example2.getKeys([]) // output: ["id", "name" ]
```

Comment: You have this answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909566/get-keys-of-a-typescript-interface-as-array-of-strings).

Comment: Pls keep in mind, generics are living in type scope while you want to obtain a value. These are two different worlds

Comment: Why are you passing an empty array to `getKeys`? If I understand your code correctly you rather want to pass `obj` to that function.

Comment: Typescript's types are totally erased when your code is compiled to Javascript, so you have to think how you would solve this problem in Javascript, write that, and then write the appropriate type annotations.

Answer (score 2):

The generic type is only a type, so you need to pass in an actual object that matches it to the constructor. Only then can you get the keys.

Also, a getter doesn't take any parameters, so I removed them.

Something like this:

```
export class GenericExample<T>{
   
 private _keys: Array<keyof T>;

 constructor(obj: T)
 {
      // The keys from generic type T are only types,
      // so you need to pass in an object that matches T
      // to the constructor. Then we can do this:
      this._keys = Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>;
 }

  get keys()
  {
    return this._keys;
  }
}

// Usage

const obj = { foo: "foo", bar: "bar" };

const instance = new GenericExample(obj);

// instance.keys infer to ("foo" | "bar")[] and will return ["foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: i updated my question for better understanding

Comment: @Patrick Updated my answer, but I'm still not certain if it's what you want!

Comment: I don't think this works, because it requires you to have obj (an instance of T). lets say you receive an array of elements T like myArray: T[], it can work if you know that the array you receive contains at least one element (in this case you just use your function with myArray[0]) but if the array is empty and you still need to access the keys of the type you wont be able to with your solution.

Answer (score -3):

You can just use `Object.keys(obj)` which will return an array of the object's keys. (In this case, `["foo", "bar"]`

Comment: i know this function. but i have to get the keys in the generic class, even when the obj (in the getKeys method) is null or empty.