# Is there a way to read property names from interface in typescript similar to reflections in c#

Tags: angular, typescript, reflection

I have an interface defined and has multiple properties. Is there a way that I could read the property names in typescript/angular.

My interface looks is something similar as below

```
    export interface InterfaceName
   {
     property1: string;
     property2: string;
     property3: number;
   }
```

Comment: There is a hacky way - check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909566/get-keys-of-a-typescript-interface-as-array-of-strings

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [tst-reflect](https://github.com/Hookyns/ts-reflection) for the TypeScript Reflection.

I've made you this StackBlitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tst-reflect-example?file=index.ts).

**How to list the properties of an Interface with `tst-reflect`?**

```js
import { getType, Property} from "tst-reflect";

interface InterfaceName
{
    property1: string;
    property2: string;
    property3: number;
}

const properties: Array<Property> = getType<InterfaceName>().getProperties();
// Do something with properties...
```

TL;DR;

In the README, there is a section [How to Start](https://github.com/Hookyns/ts-reflection#how-to-start). You have to use eg. `ttypescript` to get transformers working. TypeScript does not support transformers out of the box, only by direct calls to their Compiler API. `ttypescript` is some kind of wrap which allows you to define transformers in tsconfig.

**Copy of that How to Start:**

1. Install packages.

```
npm i tst-reflect && npm i tst-reflect-transformer -D
```

2. In order to use transformer plugin you need TypeScript compiler which supports plugins eg. package [ttypescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttypescript) or you can use [TypeScript compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) manually.

```
npm i ttypescript -D
```

3. Add transformer to `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // your options...

        // ADD THIS!
        "plugins": [
            {
                "transform": "tst-reflect-transformer"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

4. Now just transpile your code by `ttsc` instead of `tsc`

```
npx ttsc
```

**And usage with Webpack:**

Modify your webpack config. Use `options.compiler` of `ts-loader` to set `ttypescript` compiler.

```js
({
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    loader: require.resolve("ts-loader"),
    options: {
        compiler: "ttypescript"
    }
})
```

`Property` is:

```js
interface Property
{
    /**
     * Property name
     */
    readonly name: string;
    /**
     * Property type
     */
    readonly type: Type;
    /**
     * Optional property
     */
    readonly optional: boolean;
    /**
     * Access modifier
     */
    readonly accessModifier: AccessModifier;
    /**
     * Accessor
     */
    readonly accessor: Accessor;
    /**
     * Readonly
     */
    readonly readonly: boolean;
    /**
     * Returns array of decorators
     */
    getDecorators(): ReadonlyArray<Decorator>;
}
```