# Import props in Storybook select options

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I have interface specified:

```
interface Props{
   type: 'dog' | 'cat' | 'mouse' | 'turtle' | 'rabbit'
}

export default Props;
```

In reality that list of all allowed `string` values is quite long. Is it possible to populate my story in `Storybook` based on `Props`?

I tried doing this:

```
import React, {ReactElement} from 'react';
import Props from '../typings';

export default {
  title: 'Animals',
  component: Animal,
  argTypes: {
    type: {
      control: {
        type: 'select',
        options: [...Props.type],
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: i'm afraid you can't.  Interface and type can only be in the type assignment, not non-type.

Answer (score 0):

There might be tricks to do what you need, but most require you to stay in the type side. Check, [Get keys of a Typescript interface as array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909566/get-keys-of-a-typescript-interface-as-array-of-strings)

But I found one solution easy to apply.

```
class Props {
   id = ''
}

const k = Object.keys(new Props())
console.log(k)
```

If you define it as a class, and once it create a new one based on this class, then everything else becomes a instantiated variable.