# Typescript Typeguard check if array is of type

Tags: arrays, typescript, typeguards, generic-type-parameters

I want to write a typeguard to check if all children of array are of type T thus making it an Array where T is a generic type

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=35&ssc=2&pln=10&pc=1#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBFQVQSCdjIMRkbFEsx4NDtcbsGgVelMRQITiCGiOMj5MScPAAbQAuqAALygMWKEoAbwVJRx8HgwoARNJ3JgAIya3gqkrSRzCvUqgC+RqVxrVGtA2t1ACZDXbTULQM6rUaJcEMgoyMkGEtOJAJPtQMqSsl1cL+ZROMwVR7hZwadJvopLeSwABhbCwRKxOp07GiMaCphJVJhiOs-gUZz0tPh-aSnmNfkiQScshMADyqVlAB4cLwAHwACkFwqZAEo5-Se5UuXgxxOZZvo6AVPs-F1QIgGPzvsyw5BuJfQL0lCUnKh8ZkyOwlDnFAip0I+4PkiO6-s06CvO847oK2bBMUODNB4ZBeIg8B9AwwLslgKCMEm7AMMwkD8LA0DqIkyHwHoIheJqACiqwMIgCz6JqSTYpq4AOKgADkwgAHLhpqQQqAOXxkO8gi4VokBHKgjgKK40jMk4CE6MMaEiWiiDQsIlxfJIiHRCuhj4vMjAsGwXDcEEQA)

```js
// Assume arr of any type but Array
const arr: any[] = [
  {
    foo: "bleh1",
    bar: 1
  },
  {
    foo: "bleh2",
    bar: 2
  },
]

interface newType {
  foo: string
  bar: number
}

// Check that arr is an array of newType , ie arr: newType[]
const isArrayOf = <T,>(arr: any): arr is Array<T> => {
  // TypeScript mastery needed here
  return true
}

if(isArrayOf<newType>(arr)){
  arr
}
```

Comment: Got suggestion from GitHub Copilot but couldnt understand the 2nd argument 
```typescript
const isArrayOf = <T>(arr: any[], type: new (...args: any[]) => T): arr is T[] => {
  return arr.every((item) => item instanceof type)
}
```

Comment: The type system *does not exist at runtime*. You cannot check if something conforms to a generic type because there is no "geneics" nor "types" when the function runs.

Comment: The suggestion is to use a concrete type and pass in a class. However, that's not possible when the type is an interface.

Comment: I think its possible like described [here] (https://2ality.com/2020/06/type-guards-assertion-functions-typescript.html#example-of-a-user-defined-type-guard%3A-isarrayinstanceof()) but I fail to understand its working thus would like some explanation about the function arguments

Comment: Again, this works if you have a *concrete type*. Something that exists at runtime. A class. Not if you have an interface - that only exists at compiletime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing you could do is this:

```
const arr: NewType[] = [
  {
    foo: "bleh1",
    bar: 1
  },
  {
    foo: "bleh2",
    bar: 2
  },
]

interface NewType {
  foo: string
  bar: number
}

type TypeOfArrayElements<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U : never;

type ArrayType = TypeOfArrayElements<typeof arr>;
```

TypeScript will never be able to guess that the array typed as `any[]` actually contains `NewType` elements. Like everything in TypeScript, [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) are static and won't return a type dynamically based on what is passed as a parameter at runtime. But if you type it as `NewType[]`, then you can extract the `NewType` type from it.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit 1:

This answer has two shortcomings (mentioned in comments)

- The property needs not be own for it to exist on the object `x = {a: 1}; y = Object.create(x); y.b = 2`
- The function requires you to manually enumerate all the keys of the object. Thus can introduce human error

I think the solution can still be used as workaround in specific circumstances

### Original:

If an array `a` is of type `newType[]` then every element of a , consider `x = a[0]` will be of type `newType`. `x` is of type `newType` because `x` satisfies all properties and methods of type `newType`.

Thus if reversed , if `x` `y` `z` are of type `newType` and they are the only and all elements of array `a`, Thus every element of `a` are of type `newType`, which satisfies the condition for `a` to be of type `newType[]`

```js
// Check if obj has all keys props[]
const hasAllProperties = <T,>(obj: any, props: (keyof T)[]): obj is T => {
  return props.every((prop) => {
    // console.log(prop)
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)})
}

// Check that arr is an array of newType , ie arr: newType[]
const isArrayOf = <T,>(obj: any[], props: (keyof T)[]): obj is T[] => {
  // Check if every elements have all keys in props
  return obj.every((ele) => {
    // console.log(ele)
    return hasAllProperties<T>(ele,props)
  }
  )
}

if (isArrayOf<newType>(arr, ["foo", "bar"])) {
  console.log("arr is of newType[]")
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBFQVQSCdjIMRkbFEsx4NDtcbsGgVelMRQITiCGiOMj5MScPAAbQAuqAALygMWKEoAbwVJRx8HgwoARNJ3JgAIya3gqkrSRzCvUqgC%20RqVxrVGtA2t1ACZDXbTULQM6rUaJcEMgoyMkGEtOJAJPtQMqSsl1cL%20ZROMwVR7hZwadJvopLeSwABhbCwRIIpLSABWoAcwgY0GgoHikDwwgIbAIgklPMa-MrDEEFVrtFb33q%20hloAAPDheAA%20AAU8HLwqZ-Bb8DbwtnDcMqRwAEpJbvhQuK6IcDLp1GVU5UPivKu2wFIHoyHhZ7P77vz5fVaAVLzBPA7gBNA8DMO%20ra7na163qAADy5aQLAqABKu6CoO0ARVrBEicIOa7DngAS1LW87liuEGWpBObFAWiGJLEdR0tiohjIKTBJKkYYRqy-AUM49JpuG%20wdv%206R9lyeCwaksqTjOpFlkuoqSuRa4FKAm6NkSe4Hke5YiMIOCSl%200a-vmhbFqkT7fMyMCQNCwgOHoYi1vWjbCBk8ytr8JTQWQXjHo%20z6vrOtmftKF4mSUf5doBkDAaBIXuJBP6%20V4Vb9tAeEbCOgiTnOtm8PegjJaAOYlFR-qpLOQicmQTBSeOXH7HOgr8GKmqxvAhqOh6moSrun4mf%20sXxWBmrgLBZDxIIACEM3dYKFW5t4zQeH5oCIPAfQMMC7JYCgjBJuwDDMJA-CwNA6iJDt8BOR5moAKKrAwiALPompJNi40OKgADkwgAHLhpqQQqLBXxkO8ghnVokBHKgjgKK40jMk4m06MM%203Q2iiD2SKMR3BIW3RPpoCGPi8yMCwbBcNwQRAA)

Comment: `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)})` - the property needs not be own for it to exist on the object. Consider `x = {a: 1}; y = Object.create(x); y.b = 2` now `y` has both fields `a` and `b` thus satisfies `interface AB { a: number; b: number; }` however `a` is not an own property. Consider using `prop in obj`

Comment: There is also a problem with the function invocation being `isArrayOf<newType>(arr, ["foo", "bar"])` - that requires you to manually enumerate all the keys of the object. However, it's not a compilation error if you don't, thus `isArrayOf<newType>(arr, ["foo"])` would claim that `arr = [{foo: "hello}, {foo: "world"}]` is `newType[]` when it is not. This could be an issue if the interface changes, for example. Maybe the invocation was correct once but in the future somebody adds or removes a property - they now have to go and change all invocations of `isArrayOf`

Comment: The 2nd drawback can we avoided with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909566/get-keys-of-a-typescript-interface-as-array-of-strings