# How can I the take keys of some value from a type?

Tags: typescript, node-csv-parse

I tried to use csv-parse's option `cast` to convert the type.

My approach is as follows, but there are problems.

I referred to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60932900/19252706

Is it to possible to define KeysOfNumbers and KeysOfBooleans:

```
import {CastingFunction, parse} from 'csv-parse/browser/esm/sync';

const input =
  'ID,Type,From,Title,Content,Date,IsRead,IsAD\r\n1,0,Mars,My car glass was broken,How much DOGE to fix this.....,423042301654134900000,false,false';

type Mail = {
  ID: string;
  Type: number;
  From: string;
  Title: string;
  Content: string;
  Date: number;
  isRead: boolean;
  isAD: boolean;
};

// This is problem. Is this possible to fix?
type KeysOfNumbers<T> = string[];
type KeysOfBooleans<T> = string[];

const castNumberAndBoolean =
  <T>(
    keysOfNumbers: KeysOfNumbers<T>,
    KeysOfBooleans: KeysOfBooleans<T>,
  ): CastingFunction =>
  (value, context) =>
    keysOfNumbers.includes(context.column.toString())
      ? Number(value)
      : KeysOfBooleans.includes(context.column.toString())
      ? value === 'true'
        ? true
        : false
      : value;

parse(input, {
  columns: true,
  cast: castNumberAndBoolean<Mail>(['Type', 'Date'], ['isRead', 'isAD']),
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a handy helper type:

```
type KeysOfType<T, U> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U ? K : never
}[keyof T];

type TestA = KeysOfType<Mail, boolean>
// 'isRead' | 'isAD'
```

This type takes an object to map `T`, and a type for the properties to keep `U`. It iterates over each key `K` and checks if the type of that property `T[K]` extends `U`. If it does, keep the key, else throw it out by resolving to `never`. Lastly index the resulting object by its own keys to get all property types as a union.

Now you can make types that use this type:

```
type KeysOfNumbers<T> = KeysOfType<T, number>[]
type KeysOfBooleans<T> = KeysOfType<T, boolean>[]

type MailNumbers = KeysOfNumbers<Mail>
//   ('Type' | 'Date')[]

type MailBooleans = KeysOfBooleans<Mail>
//   ('isRead' | 'isAD')[]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.6.4&preserveConstEnums=true&jsx=0&preserveValueImports=false&isolatedModules=false&allowSyntheticDefaultImports=false&inlineSources=false&preserveWatchOutput=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgSwDZQLxQN4CgpQJIAiAXFAM7ABOCAdgOYDcOUAKuBCdQK4C2ARhBUa4AYhQD23EuSp0hLBMCTsylGgyYBhMdWAQdU1bKYE4ujj36CmCUgCUIcACYleYsUrjU5NgILEoru4OXlgAvoxYoJBQANIQIKQA8gBmrJAAPMwANFAAqgB8aJhMuADaMVA0UADW8WLJLAC6JMzljVAQAB661I6keVAA-LFQHBAAbgJhpbUg9U0RUdDMEOQ+RXEJKWkQ6fDIOYEe1PlYAPRnuFAAeoNYkWyx8UnJAHIWAqSZheibLzuZHJcPgCfKlRoPaJ-FIAITcxy+zB+Ty2qTYgIC8OCYIhkOg+yQ7xBFH6v2eKSJli+BNOFyut3uS1giCQcKCnlJKJebIRexZtMuuFuQA)