# Can Jest test that a class correctly implements a Typescript interface?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have a class and I want to write a Jest test to ensure that any objects instantiated from that class have keys that match an interface that the class implements.

Essentially I want to see a failing test if my class is modified in some way that no longer matches the interface that has been defined for it.

```
export class Template implements TemplateInterface { // Class 'Template' incorrectly implements interface...
// props hidden for brevity
}
```

```
it("should be an instance of InspectionTemplate", () => {
    const template = new InspectionTemplate(sampleTemplateJson); 
    expect(template).toBeInstanceOf(InspectionTemplate);  // this passes, but I want a test to fail
});
```

Any ideas? There's a long discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909566/get-keys-of-a-typescript-interface-as-array-of-strings) about how complex it is to get the keys of the interface, but I'm not entirely confident that's the way to go.

Comment: An interface just describes the expectations a user would expect something that implements the interface to do. In other words, it's a contract that makes sure the implementation matches the expectations of the user. That means you should just test the instance and make sure it behaves how you would expect it to.

Comment: The _compiler_ checks an implementation matches the interface, at least from the perspective of the types - that's its job.

Comment: I think you can only have an instance of a class. You can't have an instance of an interface.